# Prototyping JavaScript native types, discouraged?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Is it a bad idea to prototype additional features in JavaScript's native types like Array, String, Number, etc?

I think it would be great to have functionality like myArr.pop(), etc., but what if someday that becomes part of the ECMAScript x -- and differs from my implementation, so, it potentially breaks the entire software?

Comment: The people responsible for the Prototype framework don't think so.

Comment: They wouldn't let you if it couldn't be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prototype is a library that extensively extends native Javascript types and DOM classes, and shows extremely well the good, the bad and the ugly of extending Javascript native types.

The Good: You get natural-looking Javascript code.

The Bad: You forget that you are actually using Prototype - spawning confusion when you switch to a project that does not use Prototype. (Why can't I... oh, right, that was a Prototype capability.)

The Ugly: If there is a conflict for method definitions (two methods that differ in either contracts or signatures) because of conflicting libraries, the browser or the specification, you may have to modify client code to maintain compatibility. Which makes one more compatibility consideration to make in a world already plagued with them.

For the sake of compatibility and keeping my own ideas clear, I personally refrain from extending native or DOM javascript types, and prefer less intrusive libraries to Prototype.

However, if you feel at ease with these drawbacks, don't let me stop you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to replicate a method that is defined for some browsers but not others, try to get the definition to match the native implementation.

```
if(![].indexOf){
    Array.prototype.indexOf= function indexOf(what, i){
        i= i || 0;
        var L= this.length;
        while(i< L){
            if(this[i]=== what) return i;
            ++i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
if(![].map){
    Array.prototype.map= function map(fun, scope){
        var L= this.length, A= Array(this.length), i= 0, val;
        if(typeof fun== 'function'){
            while(i< L){
                if(i in this){
                    A[i]= fun.call(scope, this[i], i, this);
                }
                ++i;
            }
            return A;
        }
        else throw 'missing function argument';
    }
}
if(!''.trim){
    String.prototype.trim= function trim(){
        return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
    }
}
```

The native method will be used, if possible.
If you roll your own methods, try to give them a name that isn't likely to be pre-empted

I like to have a shuffle and a naturalSort method for arrays,
but I give them slightly off beat names.

```
Array.prototype.a1Sort= function(){
    var a, b, a1, b1, rx=  /(\d+)|(\D+)/g, rd=  /\d+/;
    return this.sort(function(as, bs){
        a= String(as).toLowerCase().match(rx);
        b= String(bs).toLowerCase().match(rx);
        while(a.length && b.length){
            a1= a.shift();
            b1= b.shift();
            if(rd.test(a1) || rd.test(b1)){
                if(!rd.test(a1)) return 1;
                if(!rd.test(b1)) return -1;
                if(a1!= b1) return a1 - b1;
            }
            else if(a1!= b1) return a1> b1? 1: -1;
        }
        return a.length - b.length;
    });
}
Array.prototype.disorder= function(force){
    var i, temp, L= this.length, A= force? this: this.concat();
    while(--L){
        i= Math.floor(Math.random()*L);
        temp= A[i];
        A[i]= A[L];
        A[L]= temp;
    }
    return A;
}
```

If you do add to the prototypes, make sure you document it and reference the doc in every script that uses them-
if anyone is ever going to work with your code, including you.