# How to get a key in a JavaScript object by its value?

Tags: javascript, object

I have a quite simple JavaScript object, which I use as an associative array. Is there a simple function allowing me to get the key for a value, or do I have to iterate the object and find it out manually?

Comment: There is no such standard function to do this. If the mapping is truly bidirectional then it is trivial to construct a "flipped" map and index that. Otherwise a simple property-iterator (with a hasOwnProperty gaurd, perhaps) and an early-return hidden inside a function does just nicely...

Comment: How could this work if an object was referenced by more than one key? `var o = []; var map = {first: o, second: o}`. What would `find_key(o)` return?

Comment: doesn't matter ;) I only intended to use it for an array with unique key-value-pairs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [best way to get the key of a key/value javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268679/best-way-to-get-the-key-of-a-key-value-javascript-object)

Comment: I've made a version without iteration https://stackoverflow.com/a/36705765/696535. It would be interesting to test all proposed solutions in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1147, accepted):

```
function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
  return Object.keys(object).find(key => object[key] === value);
}
```

ES6, no prototype mutations or external libraries.

Example,

```js
function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
  return Object.keys(object).find(key => object[key] === value);
}


const map = {"first" : "1", "second" : "2"};
console.log(getKeyByValue(map,"2"));
```

Comment: Well, really clean if you don't support IE11 :-)If so, you need a polyfill

Comment: Depending on the implementation, this probably takes *O(n)* space since `keys()` materializes the key set.

Comment: Clean but slow.

Comment: If Multiple keys have Same value use filter instead of find
`function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
  return Object.keys(object).filter(key => object[key] === value);
}`

Comment: Lol. This is not slow, it’s O(n) which is pretty much the best possible runtime.

Comment: @BenWainwright: Θ(n) is the pretty much the worst runtime for this problem without actively trying to make a slow implementation.

Comment: @Ry- so beat it. What’s the solution in better than n? Literally every other solution I’ve seen on this page has been at *least* o(n)

Comment: @BenWainwright: Maintaining a `BiMap` or equivalent (Alethes’s answer) is often the efficient O(1) approach to the broader problem, but even for one-offs it’s at least possible to iterate with `for in` and break upon finding a match, rather than creating an entire array of keys ahead of time, leading to a best case better than the worst case. That is, O(position) instead of O(size). (The only answer on this page worse than O(size) is the silly JSON one.)

Comment: @Ry- Alethes answer is not a valid answer to the question as asked ... yeah sure there are plenty of things you can do if you change the preconditions but the asker asked how to find a value out of a plain object.

Comment: My comment referred to worst case runtime (you know... big O). An early exit from a loop is irrelevant.

Comment: To repeat, O(n) is the best possible *worst case runtime*

Comment: this fails when its consequitive values ex -

const map = {"first" : "2", "second" : "2"};
console.log(getKeyByValue(map,"2"));

Comment: What about nested properties?

Comment: what happens if the value stored is an object?

Comment: Not working when u have camelCase keys and space between the value name, like 'userGroup': 'User Group'...

Answer (score 192):

No standard method available. You need to iterate and you can create a simple helper:

```
Object.prototype.getKeyByValue = function( value ) {
    for( var prop in this ) {
        if( this.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
             if( this[ prop ] === value )
                 return prop;
        }
    }
}

var test = {
   key1: 42,
   key2: 'foo'
};

test.getKeyByValue( 42 );  // returns 'key1'
```

**One word of caution**: Even if the above works, its generally a bad idea to extend any host or native object's `.prototype`. I did it here because it fits the issue very well. Anyway, you should probably use this function outside the `.prototype` and pass the object into it instead.

Comment: Actually it's ok if you know things like that the for-in loop goes down the property chain which means "for(var key in obj)" would give you "getKeyByValue" as "key" at some point.

Comment: Oh man I love how this stealthfully returns undefined if the value doesn't exist. Well done. Also, just a point of interest, this would perform O(n) so if the object had a ton of properties (like a list of people in a big city and their addresses), you'd probably want a more efficient search. Maybe sort values and binary search? Eh?

Comment: Thanks a lot, by the time I saw bad idea, I wonder why then I searched through this and added here for this answer enhancement and extensive reading. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085240/prototyping-javascript-native-types-discouraged

Comment: @jAndy it is NOT ===, it is ==. Your code does not work with ===. It returns undefined.

Comment: I think Converting it to a string would be better to fix type errors just add `.toString()` like `obj[ key ].toString()` and to the value if desired...

Comment: Definitely follow the word of caution and pass the object into a standard function instead. This can save you some trouble :)

Comment: This mutates the prototype of Object, which is a horrible approach to doing this. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807805/why-is-mutating-the-prototype-of-an-object-bad-for-performance

Comment: @JonKoops: You’re right that adding to `Object.prototype` is bad, but that question link is about changing the prototype of *an* object.

Answer (score 172):

As said, iteration is needed. For instance, in modern browser you could have:

```
var key = Object.keys(obj).filter(function(key) {return obj[key] === value})[0];
```

Where `value` contains the value you're looking for.
Said that, I would probably use a loop.

Otherwise you could use a proper "hashmap" object - there are several implementation in JS around - or implement by your own.

**UPDATE 2018**

Six years passed, but I still get some vote here, so I feel like a more modern solution – for modern browser/environment – should be mentioned in the answer itself and not just in the comments:

```
const key = Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key] === value);
```

Of course it can be also a function:

```
const getKeyByValue = (obj, value) => 
        Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key] === value);
```

Comment: ES6: `Object.keys(obj).or(o=>o[key] === value)`

Comment: Unfortunately the arrow function is not any "modern" browser yet, so it's a bit useless at the moment – I'm using it in jetpack on Firefox Nightly, it will be in Firefox 22. Anyway, I'm not aware about any `or` array's method, and it's not clear to me its purpose here: I will appreciate some additional detail! :)

Comment: As for arrow, it's coming and I'm waiting for it :) As for `or` sure! It was only recently evaluated and accepted (I don't think anyone implements it yet). What it does is find the first element of an array matching a predicate and return it. So `[1,2,3,4].or(x=>x>2)` would return `3` and `[1,2,3,4,5].or(x=>x<3)` would return `1`. Something like C#'s FirstOrDefault :)

Comment: Yeah, arrow is coming but it will takes to be used widely – unless as I do, someone's working on a specific engine. I wasn't aware of new proposal for ES6, I thought was pretty closed: do you have a link about the `or` method? From what you mentioned it seems that it returns the item that match the predicate "or" the array itself?

Comment: Looks like it was renamed to `Array.prototype.find` and `Array.prototype.findIndex` (for finding the index rather than the element :) https://github.com/Ralt/or/issues/1#issuecomment-14940411

Comment: Isn't this very inefficient for objects with lots of keys? `filter` will traverse the entire set of keys first, and then the first element is taken. It would be more efficient to bail out after finding the first (if any) match.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum `Object.keys(movementArr).or(o => console.log('OP', o));` I'm getting error with your code. Help me please?

Comment: @sg552 as it was mentioned later, `or` was renamed. I believe now you should use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Comment: `entries` or `keys` are "iteration", just not explicit one – my original comment doesn't use `for` loop but I consider this iteration anyway. The link you posted doesn't add anything more than what was said in this thread, honestly.

Comment: Can you please provide a complete example?

Comment: You mean something like: `const data = {"foo": 10, "bar": 20}; console.log(getKeyByValue(data, 20))`? I can update the answer if that was what you asked!

Answer (score 104):

**Shortest One Liners**

```
let key = Object.keys(obj).find(k=>obj[k]===value);
```

---

Return all keys with the value:

```
let keys = Object.keys(obj).filter(k=>obj[k]===value);
```

---

If value is an `Array` or `Object`:

```
let keys = Object.keys(obj).filter(k=>JSON.stringify(obj[k])===JSON.stringify(value));
```

Answer (score 93):

With the [Underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/) library:

```
var hash = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2
};

(_.invert(hash))[1]; // => 'foo'
```

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Not everyone wants to load a 5kb library for a simple key lookup ;)

Comment: Just FYI for anyone looking for a solution that will get you ALL keys that match a value: this will not work.

Comment: underscore keys will work too. http://underscorejs.org/#keys   _.keys({one: 1, two: 2, three: 3});
=> ["one", "two", "three"]

Comment: _.invert doesn't work where the values include objects as the default string serialization collides. You might use this abomination: `_.chain(hash).pairs().findWhere({1: 1}).value()[0] `

Comment: **A word of caution:** According to the [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#invert): "For this to work, all of your object's values should be unique and string serializable."

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer, it propose a solution via a library that force a change in the current code structure

Comment: @Doorknob problems with 5kb could be solved with `npm i lodash/invert`

Answer (score 52):

The lodash way https://lodash.com/docs#findKey

```js
var users = {
  'barney':  { 'age': 36, 'active': true },
  'fred':    { 'age': 40, 'active': false },
  'pebbles': { 'age': 1,  'active': true }
};

_.findKey(users, { 'age': 1, 'active': true });
// → 'pebbles'
```

Comment: Lodash is clearly the best solution for this issue. Better even, I find, than the underscore way.

Comment: FYI, "the underscore way": `_.findKey(users, { 'age': 1, 'active': true });` ...it's the same

Comment: if array is the value you need to use:-
let obj = { a: [1, 2], b: [3, 4], c: [5, 6] }
_.findKey(obj, function(val) {
    return _.isEqual(val, [5, 6]);
});

Comment: if your values are simple, like strings or integers, then contrary to expectation this will not work. e.g. `_.find_key({a: "A", b:"B"}, "B"})` returns`undefined` so as stated [here](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/528) you need to do  `_.find_key({a: "A", b:"B"}, _.partial(_.isEqual,"B")})`

Comment: @ryan2johnson9 That's my problem with Lodash. I'm having a hard time understanding some functions (apparently I'm the only one). But thanks anyway, it works. I found another, shorter solution. It causes overheap on bigger objects so be careful with this one.
`_.invert(haystack)[needle]`

Comment: @arik: Considering the traffic this question gets, please consider updating which answer is accepted.

Comment: To extend the comment by @ryan2johnson9, when the values are primitives (string, integers, ...) you need to use `_.findKey({a: "A", b: "B"}, value => value === "B") // => "b"` because the 2nd argument is a predicate. The shorthand `_.findKey({...}, "B")` will look for a property called `B`: `{b: { B: ... } }`

Answer (score 45):

```
function extractKeyValue(obj, value) {
    return Object.keys(obj)[Object.values(obj).indexOf(value)];
}
```

Made for closure compiler to extract key name which will be unknown after compilation

**More sexy version but using future `Object.entries` function**

```js
function objectKeyByValue (obj, val) {
  return Object.entries(obj).find(i => i[1] === val);
}
```

Edit 2023: Although `.entries()` is now widely supported, in the end the first version is still better due to not iterating on a JS callback but using native `indexOf`.

Comment: I think this is the best one for 2017+ since it uses plain JavaScript.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work if you have two or more numbers that have the same value

Comment: @SamuelChen that's right but if it worked it would mean an array is needed as a result. Where `Object.entries(obj).find(i => i[1] === val);` use `filter` instead `Object.entries(obj).filter(i => i[1] === val);`

Comment: Use destructuring to make it even better `Object.entries(obj).find( ([ key, value ]) => value === val);`

Comment: You got the fastest solution as of 2021. Object.values(...).find(...) is 10% slower for a 15 properties object, I wonder how better that could be for a big object.

Comment: @Elmatou interesting observation, I didn't know that. I'm wondering if that's also true on bigger samples. The thing with benchmarking JS on small samples are very random results

Comment: this is actually not going to return the key using the Object.entries method. Suggested edit incoming. (Arge too many pending edits)

Answer (score 30):

**I use this function:**

```
Object.prototype.getKey = function(value){
  for(var key in this){
    if(this[key] == value){
      return key;
    }
  }
  return null;
};
```

**Usage:**

```
// ISO 639: 2-letter codes
var languageCodes = {
  DA: 'Danish',
  DE: 'German',
  DZ: 'Bhutani',
  EL: 'Greek',
  EN: 'English',
  EO: 'Esperanto',
  ES: 'Spanish'
};

var key = languageCodes.getKey('Greek');
console.log(key); // EL
```

Comment: +1 neat solution. 
But i have a question: Shouldn't you always check for `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)` or is it unnecessary in this case ?

Comment: Mutating the Object prototype is bad practice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807805/why-is-mutating-the-prototype-of-an-object-bad-for-performance

Answer (score 22):

> **Non-iteratable solution**

Main function:

```
var keyByValue = function(value) {

    var kArray = Object.keys(greetings);        // Creating array of keys
    var vArray = Object.values(greetings);      // Creating array of values
    var vIndex = vArray.indexOf(value);         // Finding value index 

    return kArray[vIndex];                      // Returning key by value index
}
```

Object with keys and values:

```
var greetings = {
    english   : "hello",
    ukranian  : "привіт"
};
```

Test:

```
keyByValue("привіт");
// => "ukranian"
```

Comment: simpler: 
`Object.keys(greetings )[Object.values(greetings ).indexOf('привіт')]`

Answer (score 18):

> Keep your ***prototype*** clean.

```
function val2key(val,array){
    for (var key in array) {
        if(array[key] == val){
            return key;
        }
    }
 return false;
}
```

Example:

```
var map = {"first" : 1, "second" : 2};
var key = val2key(2,map); /*returns "second"*/
```

Answer (score 17):

If you are working with **Underscore** or **Lodash** library, you can use the [_.findKey](https://lodash.com/docs/#findKey) function:

```
var users = {
  'barney':  { 'age': 36, 'active': true },
  'fred':    { 'age': 40, 'active': false },
  'pebbles': { 'age': 1,  'active': true }
};

_.findKey(users, function(o) { return o.age < 40; });
// => 'barney' (iteration order is not guaranteed)

// The `_.matches` iteratee shorthand.
_.findKey(users, { 'age': 1, 'active': true });
// => 'pebbles'

// The `_.matchesProperty` iteratee shorthand.
_.findKey(users, ['active', false]);
// => 'fred'

// The `_.property` iteratee shorthand.
_.findKey(users, 'active');
// => 'barney'
```

Answer (score 16):

I created the *bimap* library (https://github.com/alethes/bimap) which implements a powerful, flexible and efficient JavaScript bidirectional map interface. It has no dependencies and is usable both on the server-side (in Node.js, you can install it with `npm install bimap`) and in the browser (by linking to *lib/bimap.js*).

Basic operations are really simple:

```
var bimap = new BiMap;
bimap.push("k", "v");
bimap.key("k") // => "v"
bimap.val("v") // => "k"

bimap.push("UK", ["London", "Manchester"]);
bimap.key("UK"); // => ["London", "Manchester"]
bimap.val("London"); // => "UK"
bimap.val("Manchester"); // => "UK"
```

Retrieval of the key-value mapping is equally fast in both directions. There are no costly object/array traversals under the hood so the average access time remains constant regardless of the size of the data.

Comment: One of the only solutions that doesn't require iteration (either in the solution itself, the standard library or another library).

Answer (score 14):

this worked for me to get key/value of object.

```js
let obj = {
  'key1': 'value1',
  'key2': 'value2',
  'key3': 'value3',
  'key4': 'value4'
}

Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) {
  console.log("key with value: " + k + " = " + obj[k])
})
```

Comment: That doesn't address the question, though, and in general, `map` should be used only if you need its return value--not as a general iterator

Comment: This does not answer the question, that is, "get a key by its value." This answer merely show you how to iterate through an object by key.

Answer (score 8):

didn't see the following:

```js
const obj = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Den'
};

function getKeyByValue(obj, value) {
  return Object.entries(obj).find(([, name]) => value === name);
}

const [ key ] = getKeyByValue(obj, 'Den');
console.log(key)
```

Answer (score 5):

Since the values are unique, it should be possible to add the values as an additional set of keys. This could be done with the following shortcut.

```
var foo = {};
foo[foo.apple = "an apple"] = "apple";
foo[foo.pear = "a pear"] = "pear";
```

This would permit retrieval either via the key or the value:

```
var key = "apple";
var value = "an apple";

console.log(foo[value]); // "apple"
console.log(foo[key]); // "an apple"
```

This does assume that there are no common elements between the keys and values.

Comment: One of the only solutions that doesn't require iteration (either in the solution itself, the standard library or another library).

Comment: The OP did say that key/value pairs were all unique therefore this low-tech answer is just fantastic! Well done ;)

Answer (score 5):

Given `input={"a":"x", "b":"y", "c":"x"}` ...

- **To use the first value** (e.g. `output={"x":"a","y":"b"}`):

```js
input = {
  "a": "x",
  "b": "y",
  "c": "x"
}
output = Object.keys(input).reduceRight(function(accum, key, i) {
  accum[input[key]] = key;
  return accum;
}, {})
console.log(output)
```

- **To use the last value** (e.g. `output={"x":"c","y":"b"}`):

```js
input = {
  "a": "x",
  "b": "y",
  "c": "x"
}
output = Object.keys(input).reduce(function(accum, key, i) {
  accum[input[key]] = key;
  return accum;
}, {})
console.log(output)
```

- **To get an array of keys for each value** (e.g. `output={"x":["c","a"],"y":["b"]}`):

```js
input = {
  "a": "x",
  "b": "y",
  "c": "x"
}
output = Object.keys(input).reduceRight(function(accum, key, i) {
  accum[input[key]] = (accum[input[key]] || []).concat(key);
  return accum;
}, {})
console.log(output)
```

Comment: this is definitely the best answer , but i was scratching my head over a way to transform it in order to return only the key for a given object, ie be functionnally equivalent to indexOf for an array.

Comment: Unless memory is a constraint and you are willing to spend a lot of processing power to look through the object many times over, just save the "output" as indicated above to a variable and look up the result in there... like `output['x']` . Is that what you were asking?

Answer (score 4):

This is a small extension to the Underscorejs method, and uses **Lodash** instead:

```
var getKeyByValue = function(searchValue) {
  return _.findKey(hash, function(hashValue) {
    return searchValue === hashValue;
  });
}
```

[**FindKey**](http://lodash.com/docs#findKey) will [search and return the first key](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/2.4.1/dist/lodash.compat.js#L2275) which matches the value.
If you want the last match instead, use [FindLastKey](http://lodash.com/docs#findLastKey) instead.

Answer (score 4):

**ES6** methods:

```
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(a).map(b => b.reverse()))['value_you_look_for']
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Lodash solution to this that works for flat key => value object, rather than a nested object. The accepted answer's suggestion to use `_.findKey` works for objects with nested objects, but it doesn't work in this common circumstance.

This approach inverts the object, swapping keys for values, and then finds the key by looking up the value on the new (inverted) object. If the key isn't found then `false` is returned, which I prefer over `undefined`, but you could easily swap this out in the third parameter of the `_.get` method in `getKey()`.

```js
// Get an object's key by value
var getKey = function( obj, value ) {
 var inverse = _.invert( obj );
 return _.get( inverse, value, false );
};

// US states used as an example
var states = {
 "AL": "Alabama",
 "AK": "Alaska",
 "AS": "American Samoa",
 "AZ": "Arizona",
 "AR": "Arkansas",
 "CA": "California",
 "CO": "Colorado",
 "CT": "Connecticut",
 "DE": "Delaware",
 "DC": "District Of Columbia",
 "FM": "Federated States Of Micronesia",
 "FL": "Florida",
 "GA": "Georgia",
 "GU": "Guam",
 "HI": "Hawaii",
 "ID": "Idaho",
 "IL": "Illinois",
 "IN": "Indiana",
 "IA": "Iowa",
 "KS": "Kansas",
 "KY": "Kentucky",
 "LA": "Louisiana",
 "ME": "Maine",
 "MH": "Marshall Islands",
 "MD": "Maryland",
 "MA": "Massachusetts",
 "MI": "Michigan",
 "MN": "Minnesota",
 "MS": "Mississippi",
 "MO": "Missouri",
 "MT": "Montana",
 "NE": "Nebraska",
 "NV": "Nevada",
 "NH": "New Hampshire",
 "NJ": "New Jersey",
 "NM": "New Mexico",
 "NY": "New York",
 "NC": "North Carolina",
 "ND": "North Dakota",
 "MP": "Northern Mariana Islands",
 "OH": "Ohio",
 "OK": "Oklahoma",
 "OR": "Oregon",
 "PW": "Palau",
 "PA": "Pennsylvania",
 "PR": "Puerto Rico",
 "RI": "Rhode Island",
 "SC": "South Carolina",
 "SD": "South Dakota",
 "TN": "Tennessee",
 "TX": "Texas",
 "UT": "Utah",
 "VT": "Vermont",
 "VI": "Virgin Islands",
 "VA": "Virginia",
 "WA": "Washington",
 "WV": "West Virginia",
 "WI": "Wisconsin",
 "WY": "Wyoming"
};

console.log( 'The key for "Massachusetts" is "' + getKey( states, 'Massachusetts' ) + '"' );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution first:

For example, I suppose that we have an object that contains three value pairs:

```
function findKey(object, value) {

    for (let key in object)
        if (object[key] === value) return key;

    return "key is not found";
}

const object = { id_1: "apple", id_2: "pear", id_3: "peach" };

console.log(findKey(object, "pear"));
//expected output: id_2
```

We can simply write a findKey(array, value) that takes two parameters which are an object and the value of the key you are looking for. As such, this method is reusable and you do not need to manually iterate the object every time by only passing two parameters for this function.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/rTazZ/2/

```
var a = new Array(); 
    a.push({"1": "apple", "2": "banana"}); 
    a.push({"3": "coconut", "4": "mango"});

    GetIndexByValue(a, "coconut");

    function GetIndexByValue(arrayName, value) {  
    var keyName = "";
    var index = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayName.length; i++) { 
       var obj = arrayName[i]; 
            for (var key in obj) {          
                if (obj[key] == value) { 
                    keyName = key; 
                    index = i;
                } 
            } 
        }
        //console.log(index); 
        return index;
    }
```

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr : Following link can answer you question better - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423493/what-is-the-performance-of-objects-arrays-in-javascript-specifically-for-googl

Answer (score 2):

Or, easier yet - create a new object with the keys and values in the order you want then do look up against that object. We have had conflicts using the prototype codes above. You don't have to use the String function around the key, that is optional.

```
 newLookUpObj = {};
 $.each(oldLookUpObj,function(key,value){
        newLookUpObj[value] = String(key);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Came here (in 2022) looking for a close variation of OP's question. Variation:

> How to find an object key based on a value, where keys may hold collections of values?

For this use case, switch from equality (`===`) to [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
const foo = ['a', 'b','c'];
const bar = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
const bat = [2, 5, 'z'];
const obj = {foo: foo, bar: bar, bat: bat};

const findMe = (v) => {
  return Object.keys(obj).filter((k) => obj[k].includes(v))
}

findMe('y') // ['bar']
findMe('z') // ['bar', 'bat']
```

Answer (score 1):

I typically recommend lodash rather than underscore.

If you have it, use it.

If you don't, then you should consider using the lodash.invert npm package, which is pretty tiny.

Here's how you can test it using gulp:

1) Create a file called gulpfile.js with the following contents:

```
// Filename: gulpfile.js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var invert = require('lodash.invert');   
gulp.task('test-invert', function () {
  var hash = {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2
  };
  var val = 1;
  var key = (invert(hash))[val];  // << Here's where we call invert!
  console.log('key for val(' + val + '):', key);
});
```

2) Install the lodash.invert package and gulp

```
$ npm i --save lodash.invert && npm install gulp
```

3) Test that it works:

```
$ gulp test-invert
[17:17:23] Using gulpfile ~/dev/npm/lodash-invert/gulpfile.js
[17:17:23] Starting 'test-invert'...
key for val(1): foo
[17:17:23] Finished 'test-invert' after 511 μs
```

**References**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.invert

https://lodash.com/

[Differences between lodash and underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789618/differences-between-lodash-and-underscore)

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp

Comment: Why is Gulp involved here? Just run the script…

Answer (score 1):

#### As if this question hasn't been beaten to a pulp...

Here's one just for whatever curiosity it brings you...

If you're sure that your object will have only string values, you could really exhaust yourself to conjure up this implementation:

```
var o = { a: '_A', b: '_B', c: '_C' }
  , json = JSON.stringify(o)
  , split = json.split('')
  , nosj = split.reverse()
  , o2 = nosj.join('');

var reversed = o2.replace(/[{}]+/g, function ($1) { return ({ '{':'}', '}':'{' })[$1]; })
  , object = JSON.parse(reversed)
  , value = '_B'
  , eulav = value.split('').reverse().join('');

console.log('>>', object[eulav]);
```

Maybe there's something useful to build off of here...

Hope this amuses you.

Answer (score 1):

Underscore js solution

```
let samplLst = [{id:1,title:Lorem},{id:2,title:Ipsum}]
let sampleKey = _.findLastIndex(samplLst,{_id:2});
//result would be 1
console.log(samplLst[sampleKey])
//output - {id:2,title:Ipsum}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an object with **array values**. Here is a good example. Let us suppose you want to show an icon based on the extension of the file you have. All the extensions with the same icon go under the same object value.

> Note: wrap the cases here in an object is better than do a switch with a lot of cases.

Check the code snippet below (written in **es6**) to see how we return the specific key for the specific extension.

I got the list of extensions from this [git repo](https://github.com/Drawbotics/file-icons)

```js
// Oject that contains different icons for different extentions
const icons = {
    "music": ["mp3", "m4a", "ogg", "acc", "flac","m3u", "wav"],
    "video": ["mp4","webm", "mkv", "avi", "mov", "m4v", "mpeg"],
    "image": ["jpg", "gif", "png", "jpeg", "tif", "psd", "raw", "ico"],
    "archives": ["zip", "rar", "tar", "dmg", "jar"],
    "3d-files": ["3ds", "dwg", "obj", "dae", "skp", "fbx"],
    "text": ["doc", "rtf", "txt", "odt", "tex"],
    "vector-graphics":["ai", "svg"],
    "pdf": ["pdf"],
    "data": ["xml", "csv", "xls"]
}

const get_icon_Key =( icons_object,file_extention) => {
   // For each key we chack if the value is contained in the list of values
   let key = Object.keys(icons_object).find(
    k=> icons[k].find(
            // At this leve we check if the extention exist in the array of the specific object value ie. 'music', 'video' ...
            icons_ext => icons_ext === file_extention)  
            // if we find it means this is the key we are looking for
            ? true: false);
    return key
}

console.log(`The icon of for mp3 extention is: => ${get_icon_Key(icons,"mp3")}`)
console.log(`The icon of for mp4 extention is: => ${get_icon_Key(icons,"mp4")}`)
```

Comment: Why are you referencing the outer icons object in the function if you pass it in any way as icons_object?

Answer (score 0):

Really straightforward.

```
const CryptoEnum = Object.freeze({
                    "Bitcoin": 0, "Ethereum": 1, 
                    "Filecoin": 2, "Monero": 3, 
                    "EOS": 4, "Cardano": 5, 
                    "NEO": 6, "Dash": 7, 
                    "Zcash": 8, "Decred": 9 
                  });

Object.entries(CryptoEnum)[0][0]
// output => "Bitcoin"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I’m late but what do you think about this **EMCMAScript 2017** solution I made today ? It handles multiple matchs because what happens if two keys have the same values ? This is why I created this little snippet.

When there’s one match, it returns just a string but when there are several matchs, it returns an array.

```js
let object = { nine_eleven_was_a_inside_job: false, javascript_isnt_useful: false }

// Complex, dirty but useful. Handle mutiple matchs which is the main difficulty.
Object.prototype.getKeyByValue = function (val) {
  
  let array = [];
  let array2 = [];
  
  // Get all the key in the object.
  for(const [key] of Object.entries(this)) {
    if (this[key] == val) {
      // Putting them in the 1st array.
      array.push(key)
    }
  }
  
  // List all the value of the 1st array.
  for(key of array) {
    // "If one of the key in the array is equal to the value passed in the function (val), it means that 'val' correspond to it."
    if(this[key] == val) {
      // Push all the matchs. 
      array2.push(key);
    }
  }
  
  // Check the lenght of the array.
  if (array2.length < 2) {
    // If it's under 2, only return the single value but not in the array. 
    return array2[0];
  } else {
    // If it's above or equal to 2, return the entire array.
    return array2; 
  }
}

/*

Basic way to do it wich doesn't handle multiple matchs.

let getKeyByValue = function (object, val) {
  for(const [key, content] of Object.entries(object)) {
    if (object[key] === val) {
      return key
    }
  }
}
*/

console.log(object.getKeyByValue(false))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use simple function to get the value passed key something below

```
const getKeyByValue = (object, value) => Object.keys(object).find(key => object[key] === value)
```

Answer (score -2):

**Keep it simple!**

You don't need to filter the object through sophisticated methods or libs, Javascript has a built in function called **Object.values**.

Example:

```
let myObj = {jhon: {age: 20, job: 'Developer'}, marie: {age: 20, job: 
'Developer'}};

function giveMeTheObjectData(object, property) {
   return Object.values(object[property]);
}

giveMeTheObjectData(myObj, 'marie'); // => returns marie: {}
```

This will return the object property data.

**References**

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values