# get index of json key using php

Tags: php, json

I want to find index of key from json array similar to this question [Get index of a key in json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218448/get-index-of-a-key-in-json)
but i need the solution using php.

here is my json (partial data)

```
{   
"currentOver":{
    "events":[]
},  
"matchString":"",
"currentPlayer":5, 
"previousOvers":[], 
"innings":[],   
"scorecards":[
    {
        "batting":{
            "players":[
                        {"id":16447,"name":"Rahul Roy"},
                        {"id":12633,"name":"Sijal Thomas"},
                        {"id":16446,"name":"Mohammed Reza"},
                        {"id":16509,"name":"Asif Khan"},
                        {"id":12633,"name":"Koyel Dijesh"},
                        {"id":16468,"name":"Shahrook"},
                        {"id":64691,"name":"Shafiq"},
                        {"id":6518,"name":"Ubaidulah"}
            ]
        }
    }
]

}
```

and php

```
foreach ($read_json->scorecards->batting->players as $batsmen => $val) {    
                if($val == 5) {   // if batsman index is 5 then display his name
                    $name = $batsmen->name;

                    echo "<div>$name</div>\n"; 

                }               
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: And where is the problem? Where are you stuck with which code?

Comment: change this javascript to php function getObjectKeyIndex(obj, keyToFind) {
    var i = 0, key;

    for (key in obj) {
        if (key == keyToFind) {
            return i;
        }

        i++;
    }

    return null;
}

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this would suffice your requirement

http://codepad.org/XQDCKAsB

Find the code sample below as well.

```
       $json  = '{"currentOver":{"events": []},"matchString":"","currentPlayer":5,"previousOvers":[],"innings":[],"scorecards":[{"batting":{"players":[{"id":16447,"name":"Rahul Roy"},{"id":12633,"name":"Sijal Thomas"},{"id":16446,"name":"Mohammed Reza"},{"id":16509,"name":"Asif Khan"},{"id":12633,"name":"Koyel Dijesh"},{"id":16468,"name":"Shahrook"},{"id":64691,"name":"Shafiq"},{"id":6518,"name":"Ubaidulah"}]}}]}';

       $arr = json_decode($json);

       echo '<pre>';

       $currentPlayer = $arr->currentPlayer;

       echo $arr->scorecards[0]->batting->players[$currentPlayer-1]->name;
```

Comment: and yes as @Andrew said make sure you decrement the current player value to get the index right ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try this code.

```php
$info = json_decode('json string');
$currentPlayer = $info->currentPlayer;
$batsman = $info->scorecards[0]->batting->players[$currentPlayer];
echo "<div>{$batsman->name}</div>\n";
```

Also, note that arrays in PHP are zero-based. If `currentPlayer` index in json data is based on 1 (rare case, but it exists sometimes) you will ned to use

```php
$batsman = $info->scorecards[0]->batting->players[$currentPlayer - 1];
```

to get right item from array.

Comment: FYI,  ($currentPlayer - 1) not required for my case $currentPlayer works

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to fix your `foreach`

1. `$read_json->scorecards->batting` should become `$read_json->scorecards[0]->batting`
2. `if($val == 5)` should become `if($batsmen == 5)`
3. `$name = $batsmen->name;` should become `$name = $val->name;`

Comment: I see. But it still says below your question that the bounty is still open. You need to click on the bounty award icon next to your selected answer, as it says [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `json_decode` and `array_keys` for the array keys from the json.

```
$json = '{ "key1" : "watevr1", "key2" : "watevr2", "key3" : "watevr3" }';
$result = json_decode ($json, true);
$keys = array_keys($result);
print_r($keys); //Array ( [0] => key1 [1] => key2 [2] => key3 )
```

Comment: only count from first line till the end.

Comment: Your partial json is not valid.

Comment: json is only for reference. it is valid json

Comment: in other words how can i display only the 5th line

Comment: please, run your json [here](http://php.fnlist.com/php/json_decode), and if works then let me do what you want?

Comment: Please check above updated json. Now i want to get player name which is on 5th line. i.e.,  "Koyel Dijesh".  the line number is not constant it varies from 1 to 8.

Comment: What is the criteria to display the name of the batsmen can you please be more clear ?

Comment: sorry i missed one line in json i have added now. it is from json itself "currentPlayer":5

Comment: So if im not wrong you want to display the name of the current player depending on the currentplayer value choosing from the players list ?

Comment: @BlackBurn027 . Yes, you are right.  your above approach is good but let me check if it helps me. Thanks

Comment: @BlackBurn027 i think your solution will work. I am just wondering why did I forget to do that way..

Answer (score 2):

In [Php](http://pedagogy.kinja.com/building-a-website-with-php-7-guide-1782080220), You can use the code below, if you wan to fix it using `foreach` loop

```
foreach($json->entries as $row)

{

    foreach($row as $key => $val)
    {
        echo $key . ': ' . $val;
        echo '<br>';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

please have a look  following code

```
$json=json_decode($data)->scorecards[0]->batting->players;
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
  if($key==5){
    echo $value->name ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using converting JSON string to Array

```
$json_str = '{   
"currentOver":{
    "events":[]
},  
"matchString":"",
"currentPlayer":5, 
"previousOvers":[], 
"innings":[],   
"scorecards":[
    {
        "batting":{
            "players":[
                        {"id":16447,"name":"Rahul Roy"},
                        {"id":12633,"name":"Sijal Thomas"},
                        {"id":16446,"name":"Mohammed Reza"},
                        {"id":16509,"name":"Asif Khan"},
                        {"id":12633,"name":"Koyel Dijesh"},
                        {"id":16468,"name":"Shahrook"},
                        {"id":64691,"name":"Shafiq"},
                        {"id":6518,"name":"Ubaidulah"}
            ]
        }
    }
]

}';
```

Decode your JSON string using "json_decode" and you get array

```
$json_decode_str = json_decode($json_str, true);
```

Now using foreach you can do anything

```
if($json_decode_str['scorecards']){

    foreach($json_decode_str['scorecards'] as $scorecard){

        $player_index = 1;
        if($scorecard['batting']['players']){

            foreach($scorecard['batting']['players'] as $player){

                if($player_index == 5){
                    echo $player['name'];
                }

                $player_index++;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Maybe this one help you :)