# jQuery inArray doesn't work

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm building a website and I have some data within php variables.
I'm trying to use that data for jQuery engine for Java enabled browsers.

I came across the problem with using php variables within jQuery script:

Here's the code I can't get to work.

//PHP array:

```
$filters['ab']='text a';
$filters['cd']='text b';
```

// jQuery script:

```
// Key I want to find in array
var test = "ab";

// Reading php array into JSON
filters = $.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($filters); ?>');

// Trying to use JSON data to create Array using original keys and values
var filtersArray = new Array();
$.each(filters, function(key) {
    filtersArray[key] = $(filters).attr(key);
});  
alert(filtersArray['ab']); returns "text a";  // Seems to be working

// Trying to find the test variable value
filterIndex = $.inArray(test, filtersArray) // Not found
```

Sorry for previous careless version of post. I though shorter will be better, but in fact it came out completely useless.

Thanks

Comment: fist of all arr is not an array. its an object. try printing $.type(arr) and you'll understand what i am talking about

Comment: did you read the docs? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, I get the "arr" var this way: arr = <?php echo json_encode($filters); ?>; Is there any way to find the index of "d" within "arr" for example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript object get key by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907419/javascript-object-get-key-by-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like this

```
function inObject(obj, val) {
    return Object.keys(obj).filter(function(key) {
        return obj[key] === val;
    }).length > 0;
}
```

jsFiddle demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/VZ5A9/

See the following pages for browser compatibility as well as shims for adding support

- Object.keys - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Browser_support
- Array filter - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Browser_compatibility

#### Update

If you need to find the key, try this one (this is also more compatible with older browsers)

```
function findFirstKeyByValue(obj, val) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key] === val) {
            return key;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/VZ5A9/1/

Comment: Probably worth mentioning `keys` and `filter` cross browser support.

Comment: Phil, thank you very much. It's absolutely clear now.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this isn't working is because the variable you named `arr` isn't an array, it's an object literal. To get this code to work try this ([**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xeBQ2/1/)):

```
arr = ["b","d","f"];
uri = "d";

alert(jQuery.inArray(uri, arr));
```

Comment: It's not really a JSON object, it's an object literal.

Comment: I think the OP is probably stuck with their object so changing it to an array is not an option