# Get object property name from value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say that I have a JavaScript object like this:

```
var obj = {
    a: 1, 
    b: 2, 
    c: 3,
    d: 4
};
```

How do I get the property `c` of the object for example knowing the value `3`?

Comment: The only solution I see is to iterate through the object and find the key

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907419/javascript-object-get-key-by-value

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in method to do this, but you can easily write one

```
var obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4
};
var key;
for (var x in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(x) && obj[x] == 3) {
        key = x;
        break;
    }
}
console.log(key)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XegvW/)

Comment: `obj.hasOwnProperty(x)` what's the need of doing this check.? `x` inside that `for` must be a key from that object `obj` right?

Comment: it is to handle if it has prototypical inherited properties

Answer (score 1):

try something like iterating the object?

```
for(var property in obj) 
{
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(property) ) 
  {
    if(obj[property] === value)
      return property;
  }
}
```