# How to get key of value returned by max function in Underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am newbie for Underscore.
I am using below function to get object containing count of values occurred and which is working fine.

```
 _.countBy(data, function(value) {
             if( value[1] <10 ) return '0' ;
             if( value[1] >99 && value[1] <= 999 ) return '1';
             if( value[1] >1000 ) return '2';

          });
```

This `_.countBy` function gives me output as `{1 : 23, 2: 4}`.

So using `_.max` function I am able to get value 23

But I want to get its key (which is 1) for which max value returned.

How can I do this ?

Thanks

Comment: `_.indexOf(values, _.max(values))`? Not the most efficient, but it will work.

Comment: thats what actually I am going to try now and I saw your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Although it's very old question but you can chain your solution as well

```
var occurrenceCount = {1:15, 2:3, 3: 45, 4: 12};
var max = _.chain(occurrenceCount).max().value();
```

this will give you max value and then you can invert to find the key

```
_.chain(occurrenceCount).invert().value()[max];
```

Comment: @Pratik can you please accept the answer if that resolve your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18435833/513340) answer I am able to get key for max value using below code.

```
var occurrenceCount = _.countBy(data, function(value) {
             if( value[1] <10 ) return '0' ;
             if( value[1] >99 && value[1] <= 999 ) return '1';
             if( value[1] >1000 ) return '2';

          });
var maxValue = _.max(occurrenceCount);
var key= _.invert(occurrenceCount)[maxValue];
```

So getting key as `1` for `{1 : 23, 2: 4}`.

Comment: This won't work if there are more than one keys with the same max value e.g. if countBy returns {1 : 23, 2: 4, 0: 23 } then invert will return { 4: 2, 23, 0 }. See alternative answer using _filter.

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as this.

```
var occurrenceCount = {1:15, 2:3, 3: 45, 4: 12};
var result = _.max(_.pairs(occurrenceCount), _.last);
```

**Output**

```
[ '3', 45 ]
```

If you want only the key, you can simply do

```
var result = _.first(_.max(_.pairs(occurrenceCount), _.last));
```

**Output**

```
3
```