# Find the Key in map in javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

How to find the key from js map array of perticular value? For example:

```
var map = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'};
```

How I find the key of `value1`?

Comment: Loop over the fields of the object and check it the value is `value1`. Unless you build another data structure, nothing smarter is possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please search the web and the site, before posting new questions.

Comment: Read this link whathaveyoutried.com to post more consise question.

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.prototype.getKeyByValue = function( value ) {
    for( var prop in this ) {
        if( this.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
             if( this[ prop ] === value )
                 return prop;
        }
    }
}

var test = {
   key1: 42,
   key2: 'foo'
};

test.getKeyByValue( 42 );  // returns 'key1'
```

from: [JavaScript object get key by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907419/javascript-object-get-key-by-value)

Comment: Please didn't copy and paste [other answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9907509/218196).