# JS - Morph basetype into subtype

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

Is there an easy way in JS to change a base type into a defined subtype? And does this make any sense (does anyone have any examples of when this could be used in a reasonable and useful way).

contrived example (likely with syntax errors):

```
var animal = function(id){
  this.init(id);
}
cat.prototype.init = function(id){this.id = id;}
cat.prototype.eat = function(){something...};

var cat = function(name, fur){
  this.fur=fur;
  this.init(id);
}
cat.prototype = new animal();

var myanimal = new animal(getNextId()); //maybe it's a petstore or something that needs animals in their DB.
//myanimal needs to become a cat now.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an easy way in JS to change a base type into a defined subtype?

No. There is a complicated way though, which [changes the prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) and then re-applies the subtype constructor.

> And does this make any sense?

No, definitely not. You'd do things like this only to re-use objects ([object pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) as a performance optimisation), but [altering the `[[prototype]]` defeats that purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23807805/1048572).

Just create a new instance:

```
myanimal = new cat(myanimal.id); // use id of old animal, and overwrite variable
```

Comment: So if my objects were more complicated, I'd do something like `myanimal = animalToNewCat(myanimal);`

Comment: Yes, that would be advisable. Unless you've got a requirement to mutate the existing object.