# JavaScript Object.create style with existing object

Tags: javascript, prototype

Say I have an existing object, a, and a prototype b. I want to make a new object, c, with the values of a, but the prototype of b. Is there a nicer way than the following:

```
function Copy(object) {
    Object.assign(this, object);
}
Copy.prototype = Object.create(b);

var c = new Copy(a);
```

Edit: Is `Object.setPrototypeOf` better or worse than the question solution?

Comment: Note that `Object.assign` is part of ES6 and is currently only supported in Firefox.

Comment: Note your `c` inherits from `Copy.prototype`, which inherits from `b`. You could make `c` inherit directly from `b` using `Copy.prototype = b` instead of `Copy.prototype = Object.create(b);`.

Comment: [`setPrototypeOf` is the worst you could do](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23809148/1048572)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need of having the `Copy` constructor. Just use

```js
var c = Object.assign(Object.create(b), a);
```