# 6To5 Compiler - use __proto__ for inheritance

Tags: prototype, ecmascript-6, porting, ecmascript-5

As the output of 6to5 I've got the following code:

```
var _inherits = function (subClass, superClass) {
    if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) {
      throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass);
    }
    subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, {
      constructor: {
        value: subClass,
        enumerable: false,
        writable: true,
        configurable: true
      }
    });
    // question is about next row
    if (superClass) subClass.__proto__ = superClass;
  };
_inherits(Controller, CoreController);
```

Can anybody describe what for used updating `__proto__` property? As i try - it doesn't nothing useful

P.S. as [documentation says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) that proto should be object, but in code is used for setting function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's used for 'static" properties inheritance. Please see the code example below:

```
class Parent {
 myMethod() {}
}

console.log(Parent.prototype.myMethod); // [Function]
console.log(Parent.prototype.hasOwnProperty('myMethod')); // true
console.log(Parent.myMethod); // undefined

class Child extends Parent {}

console.log(Child.prototype.myMethod); // Function
console.log(Child.prototype.hasOwnProperty('myMethod')); // false
console.log(Child.myMethod); // undefined

Parent.myStaticProp = 42;

console.log(Parent.prototype.myStaticProp); // undefined
console.log(Parent.myStaticProp); // 42
console.log(Parent.hasOwnProperty('myStaticProp')); // true

console.log(Child.prototype.myStaticProp); // undefined
console.log(Child.myStaticProp); // 42
console.log(Child.hasOwnProperty('myStaticProp')); // false
```

Also, in the similar question on [github](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/87#issuecomment-60139066), [yuchi](https://github.com/yuchi) said:

> Notice how ‘static’ properties are added after extension.
>
> It’s deprecated because it doesn’t give the interpreter a way to know
>   beforehand that the object (function, in this case) has a different
>   prototype chain than the standard one. Every JS interpreter implements
>   it, and that’s because there’s still no perfect agreement on
>   Object.setPrototypeOf, in fact for performance reasons IMO.
>
> And looks like that 6to5 wants to be as compatible as possible to ES6
>   semantics, so setting Child.**proto** to Parent is an acceptable
>   tradeoff.

The detailed discussion you can find by the link: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/87#issuecomment-60139066

Also, you can look at the good question from [basarat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390330/basarat) about mutating [[Prototype]] and performance by the link:
[Why is mutating the [[prototype]] of an object bad for performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807805/why-is-mutating-the-prototype-of-an-object-bad-for-performance/23809148#23809148)

Comment: Your answer is useless without the link. Answers should be self-contained. Please quote the relevant part in your answer.

Comment: I'm already added the link to the long and detailed discussion from the authors of code from question, this is very useful I guess.

Comment: Again, answers should be **self-contained**. If the link is unavailable for any reason, your answer is useless. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer .

Comment: Thanks for the notice Felix Kling, I just don't took into account the fact what the link can be broken for **any reason**. Hope the answer looks good at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

> Can anybody describe what for used updating `__proto__` property?

ES6 specs that when classes inherit from each other, the resulting constructor functions should inherit from each other as well. `CoreController.isPrototypeOf(Controller)` will yield `true`.

> As i try - it doesn't nothing useful

It is very useful for inheriting static properties, which are placed on the constructor functions in JS.

```
CoreController.hi = console.log.bind(console, "hello world");
CoreController.hi(); // hello world
Controller.hi(); // error
_inherits(Controller, CoreController);
Controller.hi(); // hello world
```

> documentation says that proto should be object, but in code is used for setting function

Every function is an object in JS. It has a prototype, and it can serve as one.

Comment: This behavior can't be defined with subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { - it's common practice. What for __proto__ update?

Comment: Yes, this behaviour can't be defined using `Object.create`, as `Object.create` does not create function objects. What's your question?

Comment: Object.create - create object with all CoreController properties. And set it into prototype Controller - so controller instance will have all properties as Controller

Comment: We're not talking about Controller *instances*, but about `Controller` itself. The instance inheritance is handled by the assignment above the line of interest.

Comment: Yep. And what the matter to use proto? i can't catch (

Comment: What else would you use? OK, `Object.setPrototyeOf` should actually be shimmed :-)

Comment: @VasilVanchuk: There are only two ways to set the prototype object of an *existing* object. `__proto__` is one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer to your question, but more of a warning regarding overriding inheritance:

Assigning the `__proto__` property of an object or using the ES6 equivalent [`Object.setPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) has severe performance impacts on any code path that is touched by such an object.

[Blog post with benchmarks](http://windward.net/blogs/high-performance-javascript-assign-prototypes/) showing some of the performance impact.

Firefox emits a warning when you do this:

```
mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly;
instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create
```

To quote from [mozilla bug 984146](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=984146)

> > The __proto__ is deadly for the type inference, basically, after doing that
> >     this means that Type Inference is unable to follow any of the properties of
> >     the object as you are changing the underlying object lookup behind his back.
> >
> > This basically means that every lookup you do on this object or any object
> >     created with this constructor will fallback on a slow path for
> >     reading/writing properties to the object.  I might under estimate this
> >     issue, Eric would know better. (ni: efaust)
>
> It's even worse than that.
>
> When you set __proto__, not only are you ruining any chances you may
>   have had for future optimizations from Ion on that object, but you
>   also force the engine to go crawling around to all the other pieces of
>   TI (information about function return values, or property values,
>   perhaps) which think they know about this object and tell them not to
>   make many assumptions either, which involves further deoptimization
>   and perhaps invalidation of existing jitcode.
>
> Changing the prototype of an object in the middle of execution is
>   really a nasty sledgehammer, and the only way we have to keep from
>   being wrong is to play it safe, but safe is slow. If possible, try to
>   create directly with prototype chain you want. If we really have to
>   swizzle prototype chains around dynamically, I'm not sure I have great
>   advice as to how to minimize the performance implications of that
>   action.