# How to interpret `subclass.__proto__ === parentClass` in JavaScript inheritance?

Tags: javascript

```js
class Polygon {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "Polygon";
  }
}
class Square extends Polygon {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
console.log(Square.__proto__ === Polygon); // true  why?
console.log(Square.prototype.__proto__ === Polygon.prototype); // true
```

I can understand the second print statement being true, but I don't understand the first print statement being true.

Comment: why do you need this? mdn says it's deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: Or rather, I don't understand why Square's [[Prototype]] is Polygon? @RudyMartin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674356/6to5-compiler-use-proto-for-inheritance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783217/what-benefits-does-es2015-es6-class-syntax-provide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `extends` keyword sets up two prototype chains:

- Sets `parentClass.prototype` object as the prototype of the `childClass.prototype`
- Sets `parentClass constructor` as the prototype of the `childClass constructor`

In your case, the two prototype chains that `extends` keyword forms are as shown below:

```
Square.prototype ---> Polygon.prototype ---> Object.prototype

Square ---> Polygon ---> Function.prototype ---> Object.prototype
```

The second point is related to your question and it is done to allow the lookup of static properties on the parent constructor.

Answer (score 3):

It's so `static` fields/accessors/methods can be looked up on the parent class if it's not found on the child, for example:

```js
class Polygon {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "Polygon";
  }
  
  static staticPolygonMethod() {
    return "staticPolygon";
  }
}
class Square extends Polygon {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

console.log(Square.staticPolygonMethod()); // staticPolygon
```

As static fields/accessors/methods are added to the class itself, the `staticPolygonMethod` is set on `Polygon` class/function itself.

In this example above, `staticPolygonMethod` is not found on the `Square` class/function, so its `[[Prototype]]` is checked for the property, which is set to `Polygon`, as you've seen with the `Square.__proto__ === Polygon` check. Because `staticPolygonMethod` exists on the `Polygon` class/function, it can now be found correctly in `Square`'s prototype chain and thus used as expected on `Square`.

Comment: In other words, the extends keyword sets Polygon as the [[Prototype]] of Square. @NickParsons

Comment: @desenzhao Yes, you shouldn't expect `Square` to have a `[[Prototype]]` of `Polygon` if it's not being extended. When nothing is extended then the class's `[[Prototype]]` will be `Function.prototype`