# Warning of mutating the [[prototype]] of an object in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, firefox, d3.js

I am working with d3.js for Data visualization. I am getting the warning shown in the following image.[image] Does anyone have the  idea why is this happening and how can I solve this? The message shown in the error is following

```
mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create
```

Comment: Does this happen when you load the library, or does it come from your usage? Which line triggers this message?

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23807805/1048572) on what the message means and by what kind of code it is caused.

Comment: The error is shown when I launch the page and no data are shown

Comment: Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovsvL4g9/) . Where can such error occur in my code?

Comment: That fiddle doesn't even import d3?! In what browser are you getting this warning?

Comment: I am getting the error in firefox. But the error is not showing in chrome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71506/discussion-between-shawana-tabassum-and-bergi).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does anyone have the idea why is this happening

Looks like it's d3's fault. They seem to use it to subclass arrays [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/core/subclass.js):

```
// Until ECMAScript supports array subclassing, prototype injection works well.
var d3_subclass = function(object, prototype) {
  object.__proto__ = prototype;
};
```

> how can I solve this?

Ignore the warning. Or <s>file a bug against</s> have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1805) of d3.js.