# Extending a base page object in Protractor with __proto__

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

The following code works perfectly... but it would seem using `__proto__` is considered controversial. Is this true in the confines of Protractor/Nodejs? And if so, how else could I accomplish the same thing?

Given a basePage:

```
var BasePage = function() {
  this.to = function() {
    browser.get(this.url);
  };
};
module.exports = new BasePage;
```

And a page that would extend BasePage:

```
var basePage = require('../pages/basePage.js');

var MyPage = function() {
  this.__proto__ = basePage; // extend basePage...
  this.url = 'http://myPage.com';
};
module.exports = new MyPage;
```

When a test calls:

```
var myPage = require('../pages/myPage.js');

it('should go to page', function() {
  myPage.to();
};
```

Then win?

Comment: I think it's more conventional to call the base constructor inside the subclass constructor: `BasePage.call(this)`. That way the two prototypes are separate objects.

Comment: I would recommend you to use util.inherits: http://devdocs.io/node/util#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but it would seem using`__proto__` is considered controversial.

[Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23807805/1048572).

> Is this true in the confines of Protractor/Nodejs?

Yes, even though at least in the known environment you can be sure that it works.

> And if so, how else could I accomplish the same thing?

There is no reason to set the `__proto__` in the constructor like you do. That's what the `.prototype` property was made for! This will work exactly like your code:

```
var basePage = require('../pages/basePage.js');

var MyPage = function() {
  this.url = 'http://myPage.com';
};
MyPage.prototype = basePage; // extend basePage...
module.exports = new MyPage;
```

However, it's a bit strange that you export instances of your constructor. If your goal is to create singleton objects, [don't use constructors and `new`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10406585/1048572). If your goal is to create a "class", you should export the constructor function (and do [inheritance a bit different](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10898786/1048572)).

Comment: Thanks Bergi, this is down the line of what I was thinking... but alas, your solution fails with: 

`TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'to'`

Comment: @BrianRay: No it doesn't? Are you sure that you have placed the prototype assignment before the `module.exports = new MyPage;` line?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... I'm following your listed example as listed, and it fails. Perhaps if you expand your example to what you mean?

Comment: Ahhh... now I'm with you. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the snippet below you can play around with different ideas involving prototypal inheritance. My personal take is that it's more conventional to call the base class constructor inside the subclass constructor. That way you can use your code in any browser as well as in Node.

```js
var baseDiv = document.getElementById("base");
var subDiv = document.getElementById("sub");

var BaseClass = function BaseClassConstructor(div) {
    this.div  = div;
};

BaseClass.prototype.text = "I'm the base class!";

BaseClass.prototype.to = function BaseClassTo() {
  this.div.innerHTML = this.text;
}

// This SubClass calls the base class constructor on its "this" context.
var SubClass = function SubClassConstructor(div) {
  BaseClass.call(this, div);
};

// The prototype is then constructed by cloning the base class prototype.
SubClass.prototype = Object.create(BaseClass.prototype);

SubClass.prototype.text = "I'm the sub class!";

var b = new BaseClass(baseDiv);
var s = new SubClass(subDiv);

s.to();
b.to();
```

```html
<div id="base"></div>
<div id="sub"></div>
```