# JavaScript __proto__ not acessible

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, prototype

I was reading on the differences between the `__proto__` and the `prototype` object, but when I tried to access the `__proto__` of an instance of an object, it returned me `undefined`.

Following is the code I wrote:

```
function Student() {

}

var student = new Student();

student.constructor // works well returns function Student() {}

student.__proto__ // returns undefined.
```

I was referring [this blog](http://javascript.info/tutorial/constructor) but I saw other blogs too that show the same. We never get the prototype on the instance of an object but `__proto__` object instead that was created using the `prototype` property.

Am I missing something or `__proto__` has been removed entirely? I've tested this on Chrome version **40.0.2214.94** on Linux.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried on other browsers? If anything, __proto__ is only recently standardized in ES6, not removed.

Comment: Create a snippet here and see what it gives :)

Comment: Rejoice! Hail this browser who removed this insufferable property! @OP: Use [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf)

Answer (score 0):

The property `__proto__` is not standard in JavaScript versions below ECMA 6 so you cannot expect every broser to support that, or an equal behavior in every browser yet.
Its best to avoid using **proto** at all.
You can read about it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

And here is an interesting comment about that by brendan eich:
https://brendaneich.com/2011/01/harmony-of-my-dreams/
EDIT:

> Object.setPrototypeOf is not going to happen. Writable **proto** is a giant pain to implement (must serialize to cycle-check) and it creates all sorts of type-confusion hazards. You may think you want it as a low-level sharp instrument. JS is not that language. Higher-level forms for classes and mixins seem much better and do not involve such sharp edges.

Comment: Uh, sure that's the correct link? That https://brendaneich.com/2011/01/harmony-of-my-dreams/ article says absolutely nothing about `__proto__`.

Comment: yes: search for `__proto__`,  it's an older comment, you need to scroll down a little

Comment: ah, that specific comment. Yes, [mutating the \[\[prototype\]\] is bad](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23809148/1048572), but that's not what OP is asking about.

Comment: True, I thought it would give some background information about why using `__proto__` is controversial.