# JavaScript ES6 - Assigning methods to super

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, super, assign

I am currently trying to figure out a way to assign methods to the super object in a class, in order to extend a functionality inside a class.

I want to create a "Component" class and have each class that extends the "Component" class have different methods depending on the component needs. I want to use the term "describe" for the method that would extend the super object. Therefore, I am describing the component.

Here is an example:

```
class Component {
    constructor (args) {
        this.template = args.template;
    }

    getTemplate () {
        return this.template;
    }

    describe () {
    //The magic should happen here
    }
}
```

Class Controller describer

```
class Controller {
    constructor () {

    }

    getEvents () {
        return {};
    }
}
```

Extending the Component class.
Then, using the "describe" method to inject other methods from other classes.

```
class example extends Component {
    constructor () {
        super({template: '<div></div>'});
        super.describe({
            Controller
        });

        super.getTemplate();
        super.getEvents();
    }
}

var app = new App({
    example
});
```

Is it possible? Thank you :)

Comment: Do you want to extend `Component` or `example`? `super` refers to `Component` so extending `super` will extend all future classes that extends `Component`. It is possible but I'm not sure if that is what you want

Comment: You don't extend/subclass by adding methods to `super`.  You extend by adding methods to either a prototype that inherits from the super object or by adding methods directory to a newly created object in the constructor.

Comment: I understand, but I wanted to be able to add methods dynamicaly without affecting other classes which extends the "Component" class. So I assume the only way I can do it is to assign the methods to "this" right?

Something along the line: https://jsfiddle.net/wea4bkxf/

Comment: Yes, assign methods to `this` in the constructor.  Then those methods belong only to that particular object (or any other objects that run  that same code).  `this.myMethod = function() {...}`.

Comment: Thank you, I guess coming from other OOP backgrounds like php makea the "super" syntax looks somewhat weird at first, but well, we all like Javascript :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to undo Object.assign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462802/is-it-possible-to-undo-object-assign)