# Classical Inheritance and Object Pooling

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a project where the following inheritance structure is used:

```
var Type = function(a){
  this.a = a;
};

var SubType = function(a){
  Type.call(this, a);
};
SubType.prototype = Object.create(Type.prototype);
SubType.prototype.constructor = SubType;
```

Now, I'm trying add some object pooling to the equation. The pattern I'm currently using works something like (pseudocode):

```
Type.new = function(){
  if object available in pool
    reset popped pool object 
    return pool object
  else
    return new Type()
}
var a = Type.new();
```

Of course, the problem with using these two patterns is that constructor calls on SubType wont draw from Type's pool. Is there a way around this without moving to a factory structure? I.e. is there a way, in a constructor, to do something along the lines of:

```
var SubType = function(){
  build on top of instanceReturnedFromFunction()
};
```

Knowing it's not always consistent across contexts, I'd would also like to preserve the inheritance structure so that instanceof etc will still work:

Comment: What is a "factory structure" and why do you want to avoid that?

Comment: By factory structure, I mean refactoring from constructors / new to something along the lines of `function Type(a){ return {a: a} }`. As to why: it would involve a quantity of refactoring, and would exclude the use some inbuilt operators (instanceof etc.)

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought you meant the `Type.new` factory…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem with using this pattern is that constructor calls on `SubType` wont draw from `Type`'s pool

In fact that's not a problem, that's a necessity. `Type` and `SubType` instances do have different prototypes, you cannot use them interchangeably (and [swapping prototypes doesn't work either](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23807805/1048572)).
You definitely will need separate pools for all your classes. And you can use that `.new` factory approach without any problems - though of course you should create those factories programatically:

```
function pooledNew() {
    // `this` is the "class" constructor function
    if (!this.pool) this.pool = [];
    var instance = this.pool.length ? this.pool.pop() : Object.create(this.prototype);
    this.apply(instance, arguments); // reset / initialise
    return instance;
}
function makePooling(constr) {
    constr.new = pooledNew;
    constr.pool = [];
    var proto = constr.prototype;
    if (proto.constructor !== constr)
        proto.constructor = constr;
    if (typeof proto.destroy != "function")
        proto.destroy = function destroyInstance() {
            this.constructor.pool.push(this);
        };
    return constr;
}
```

These are designed to work flawlessly with subclassing, in your example just do

```
makePooling(Type);
makePooling(SubType);
```

In ES6, subclasses even would inherit the `new` method from their superclass constructors.

```
class Type {
    constructor(a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    destroy() { // overwriting default behaviour
        this.a = null; // for GC
        this.constructor.pool.push(this);
    }
}
makePooling(Type);

class SubType extends Type {
    // you can use super calls in both "constructor" and "destroy" methods
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for the info. I haven't got the rep to up-vote the answer yet, but I've marked it as accepted: answers my question! Thanks again.

Comment: @MrMe: You now have the privilege :-) Well-written question asker, welcome to Stack Overflow!