# Difference between Backbone.js 'constructor.prototype' and '__proto__'?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, prototype-chain

There are codes which were implemented to show inheritance in [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/).

**GrandParent.js:**

```
define([ "require", "jquery", "backbone"], function(require, $, Backbone) {

return Backbone.Model.extend({

    //for method, variable override
    name : "grandFa", //@ WILL BE Overrided
    familyName : "Song",
    age : 99,

    sayThis : function() { //@ WILL BE Overrided
        alert("GrandParent.this : "+this+" "+this.name);
    }

    });

 });
```

**Parent.js:**

```
define([ "require", "jquery", "backbone", "grandParent"], function(require, $, Backbone, GrandParent) {
    return GrandParent.extend({
        //for testing complicated this usage
        age : 50,
        //@Overrided
        name : "father",
        sayThis : function() {
            alert("Parent.this : "+this+" "+this.name);
        }
    });
});
```

**Main.js:**

```
require.config({
paths : {
        jquery : "libs/jquery-2.1.0",
        underscore : "libs/underscore-1.6.0",
        backbone : "libs/backbone-1.1.0",
        grandParent : "1-GrandParent",
        parent : "2-Parent"
    }
});

require(
["jquery","underscore", "backbone","grandParent","parent","child"], function($, _,Backbone, GrandParent, Parent, Child) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var grandParent = new GrandParent();
        var parent = new Parent();
        alert(parent.constructor.prototype.name); //=> parent
        alert(parent.__proto__.name); //=> parent   
    });
});
```

In this code `parent.constructor.prototype.name` and `parent.__proto__.name` looks totally same. Why did Backbone make 2 fields which works and looks totally same?

Is there any differences in `constructor.prototype` & `__proto__`?

Comment: Actually, neither of these fields were made by Backbone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any differences in `constructor.prototype` & `__proto__` ?

`__proto__` is actual object which is used to resolve the properties and methods on the lookup chain. JavaScript has the ability to achieve the inheritance which is done through prototypes. Every built in object can be extended using a `prototype` which is further used to create a new `__proto__` e.g.

```
function Foo()
{
}

Foo.constructor.prototype == Foo.__proto__;  // returns true
```

But what happens here...

```
Foo.prototype == Foo.__proto__;  // returns false;
```

[**Must read on this topic here!**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript).

So that is why you got same result when you alert. The thing is `__proto__` is not meant to be expose/extend and it is [**never recommended**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807805/why-is-mutating-the-prototype-of-an-object-bad-for-performance). So you should not worry about them giving the same result. Backbone may have extended the prototypes of their custom functions/methods but it is JavaScript which created the `__proto__` as a blueprint for them.

Comment: `__proto__` is a deprecated accessor property that is inherited from `Object.prototype`. The actual property lookup chain goes through `Object.getPrototypeOf(…)`