# How to create prototype chain if objects are already created

Tags: javascript, oop, object

So i have two objects

```js
var Vehicle = { 
      type:"4 wheel vehicle",
      run: function(){
        console.log(this.type + " is running.";
      }
    }
                    
var Car = {
      type:"Car"
    }
```

What should i do to assign the Prototype chain, so if I am running

```js
Car.run();
```

This should print "Car is running", I know i can definitely do

```js
var Car = Object.create(Vehicle);

Car.type = "Car";

Car.run();
```

Do i have another way to assign the prototype chain, once the object is already created.

Comment: `Object.setPrototypeOf(Car, Vehicle)`

Comment: Any specific reason of not satisfied with Object.create as this is the most widely used NON CONSTRUCTOR way of creating objects

Comment: Yes, you can, [but you should not](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23807805/1048572).

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, I was looking for same answer.