# Factory vs constructor function performance in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, constructor, prototype, factory

So, when we have a simple constructor:

```
function Vec(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

And a factory analogue:

```
function VecFactory(x, y) {
    return {
        x: x,
        y: y
    }
}
```

The performance is comparable:

```
100000000 constructors: 1874 ms
100000000 factory calls: 1782 ms
```

But when we add a prototype:

```
function VecFactory(x, y) {
    let result = {
        x: x,
        y: y
    }
    Object.setPrototypeOf(result, Vec.prototype);
    return result;
}
```

The performance drops drastically

```
100000000 factory calls: 13251 ms
```

Assigning to __proto__ makes it worse, cloning all prototype methods into every object even worse still.

So, why does this happen? Is there a way to improve factory performance?

UPD: using `Object.create` instead of `Object.setPrototypeOf`, as **Bergi** suggests, drops factory call time to around 8700 ms.

Comment: You should use `Object.create` over `Object.setPrototypeOf`

Comment: Which browser/environment (version) are you testing in? Different engines have different optimisations in place for these things.

Comment: I'm using latest chrome/v8. Using `Object.create` does reduce time to about 8700ms, thank you)

Comment: Here is an answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807805/why-is-mutating-the-prototype-of-an-object-bad-for-performance

Comment: So, messing with prototypes at object instantiation is always bad for performance. Makes sense, I guess. Sucks for factories though

Comment: They *should* be able to optimise both `Object.create` and `Object.setPrototypeOf({})` to the same performance as the constructor, but classes get special love from v8's optimiser because they are so popular. Needs more support from the community :-)

Comment: @lvl5hm Why don't you use a constructor function inside the factory? It will be one function call slower than a constructor..