# How to extend class onto class instance in javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, prototype, extends

I'm familiar with prototypes quite well and now I try to understand how classes work by testing how they look like under the hood when compiled and compare it with 'prototypal' approach.

When I use prototypes, I can "extend" one object to another with `Object.setPrototypeOf` method. I pass as the second argument anything that is of [Object] type and it works, but when I use `extends` keyword with `class`, it expects only another [class] type object.

This is the working `prototype`-like approach:

```
function Citizen(country){
  this.country = country;
}

function Student(subject){
  this.subject = subject;
}


Object.setPrototypeOf(Student.prototype,new Citizen('Poland'));

var student = new Student('IT');
console.log(student.subject); //IT
console.log(student.country); //Poland
```

So, I "extends" the Student onto Citizen **`instance`** rather than `Citizen` itself *(constructor)*. And it works just fine. I have the access to the properties of `Citizen` instance (`student.contry`).

How can I get the same result with the `class` and `extends`?
I want to achieve something like in the code below, but it throws error: `Class extends value #<Citizen> is not a constructor or null`, what seems to be not as flexible as the use of pure prototypes.

```
class Citizen {
  constructor(subject){
    this.subject = subject;
  }
}

class Student extends new Citizen('USA') { 
  //this expects CLASS rather than instance of the class
  //Error: Class extends value #<Citizen> is not a constructor or null
  constructor(subject){
    this.subject = subject;
  }
}

var student = new Student('law');

console.log(student.subject); //law
```

Comment: "*And it works just fine.*" - [No, it doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here)

Comment: Do not use `Object.setPrototypeOf` for this. Not sure where you got that from.

Comment: "*`class` seems to be not as flexible as the use of pure prototypes.*" - it never was meant to. Classes provide a relatively rigid framework that is hard to mess up.

Comment: @Bergi from mdn. and why?

Comment: [MDN itself warns you against it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf). And [for good reason](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23807805/1048572).

Comment: @Bergi Golden rule of performance: Always measure. http://jsbench.github.io/#6b02ea20162b69c083f39686b7a38b97 Performance seems OK. MDN should be updated.

Comment: @Bergi, is that mean that `extends` for the `class` is also discouraged as it works similarly under the hood?

Comment: @JeffM Instantiation is not where the problem is. (Although in this particular case  `setPrototypeOf` is not a problem indeed). Still, there's no good reason to prefer it over `Object.create` here.

Comment: @Bergi When you use setPrototypeOf then you don't have to fix the constructor property.

Comment: @Paweł No, `extends` is fine - it's more akin to `Object.create` than to `setPrototypeOf`.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the same result with the class and extends?

You can't (-ish). But more importantly, you shouldn't. Even with the prototype approach, you still shouldn't. Your prototype approach should look like this:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(Student.prototype, Citizen.prototype);
```

And likewise, your class approach should look like this:

```
class Student extends Citizen
```

And if for some reason you want your Student to have a hardcoded country, then you'd do that like this:

```
class Student extends Citizen {
    constructor(subject) {
        super("USA");
        this.subject = subject;
    }
}
```