# Redefine prototype method

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm trying to simulate the "class" syntax in JavaScript. How do I call the function from an object's prototype when redefining it? In the example, I'm trying to extend the Bear object's sound function.

```
function Animal(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Animal.prototype.sound = function() { console.log("I'm " + this.name); }

function Bear(name) {
    Animal.call(this, name)
}
Bear.prototype = new Animal();
Bear.prototype.sound = function() { this.prototype.sound(); console.log("growl!"); }

const cal = new Bear("Callisto")
cal.sound() // Should be: I'm Callisto growl!
console.log(cal)
```

Comment: [Don't use `new Animal` to create the prototype object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here)!

Comment: So, what then? This: Object.setPrototypeOf(Bear, Animal.prototype); ?

Comment: Either `Object.setPrototypeOf(Bear.prototype, Animal.prototype)` (which I'd recommend to avoid though) or `Bear.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype)`.

Comment: Could you please give a reason, why create over setPrototypeOf?

Comment: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23807805/1048572)

Comment: Thanks, that's excellent info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could directly access the method on the Animals prototype:

```
Bear.prototype.sound = function() { 
 Animal.prototype.sound.call(this); 
 console.log("growl!"); 
};
```