# Chainable promise method

Tags: javascript

How to make the following chainable methods work?

I.e `promise` method should wrap the data returned from `get` into promise.

```js
// I need to do both:

// return object directly
return client.get(args);

// return promise
return client.get(args).promise();
```

Why? There's a library that uses this signature and I need to mock it for testing.

---

#### Edit: answer applied

```js
client.get = function(args) {
  let obj = {foo: 'bar'}; // get data from somewhere
  obj.promise = function() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log(this); // {foo: 'bar'}
        resolve(this);
        // TODO: reject logic
      });
  };
  return obj;
};
```

Comment: No, you should absolutely not use `Object.setrototypeOf` here.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, you're right, did some research on that.

Comment: @Bergi I am interested in knowing why not to use `Object.setPrototypeOf` here?

Comment: @PrakashSharma a) because it's the wrong tool, there is no use for inheritance here b) because it [generally should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23807805/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. But I think your answer also has some problem. You are suggesting to add a new property to returned object itself. In that case operations like `Object.keys` might give different result then expected.

Comment: As suggested in your linked answer, `Object.create` could be the right way.

Comment: @PrakashSharma If that really is an issue, you could use `Object.defineProperty` to make it non-enumerable. But I'm not sure what the OP is really doing here so I can only speculate

Comment: @Bergi Ok. Make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for

```
client.get = function(args) {
  let obj = {foo: 'bar'}; // get data from somewhere
  obj.promse = function() {
    return Promise.resolve(this);
  };
  return obj;
};
```