# Defining inherited instance fields with class syntax in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, es6-class

The following code, though cumbersome, allows me to define a prototype with a simple property that gets inherited by objects using the prototype:

```js
const SCXMLState = Object.setPrototypeOf(
   Object.defineProperties({
      addChild() { }

      isState: true // an inherited property & value
   },{
      isSCXML: {
         get() { return this.nodeName==='scxml' }
      },
      id: {
         get() {
            return this.getAttribute('id') || (this.isSCXML ? '(scxml)' : null);
         }
      }
   }),
   Element.prototype
);

const markup = `<scxml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/07/scxml" />`;
const xmldoc = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(markup, "text/xml");
const scxml  = xmldoc.documentElement;
Object.setPrototypeOf(scxml, SCXMLState);
console.log({id: scxml.id, isState: scxml.isState});
// {id: '(scxml)', isState: true}
```

It seems more elegant (less typing, more visually clear) to use classes and inheritance…but instance fields like `isState` are not inherited via the prototype, but set on instances. Since I'm not creating the instance using `new`, the instance field does not work:

```js
class SCXMLState extends Element {
   addChild() { }

   isState = true;

   get isSCXML() {
      return this.nodeName==='scxml';
   }

   get id() {
      return this.getAttribute('id') || (this.isSCXML ? '(scxml)' : null);
   }
}

const markup = `<scxml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/07/scxml" />`;
const xmldoc = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(markup, "text/xml");
const scxml  = xmldoc.documentElement;
Object.setPrototypeOf(scxml, SCXMLState.prototype);
console.log({id: scxml.id, isState: scxml.isState});
// {id: '(scxml)', isState: undefined}
```

Note that while the rest of the code works, the `isState` instance field is not inherited, showing `undefined` instead of `true`.

Is there an alternative, hopefully ~cleaner (simpler, less typing, encapsulated) syntax to define inherited instance properties for class instances, other than:

```js
SCXMLState.prototype.isState = true
```

Comment: In the working code, `isState` is not an "instance" property, since that property is only defined on the proto object. This means that when you have multiple objects with `SCXMLState` as proto object, and you would then do  `SCXMLState.isState = false;`, that all these objects see that change. Is this the intended behaviour?

Comment: @trincot Yes, that is intended. These are properties  that are never intended to change, but of course an instance can have a value set that shadows the real value.

Comment: if it never changes there's no reason we shouldn't use getter `get isState() { return true } ` also `Object.setPrototypeOf` makes engines slower you shouldn't use it

Comment: @TachibanaShin That is certainly a functional option. Separate from my concern about performance of invoking a function call each time the property is accessed—which might get optimized away in JIT—there is a reason: it's a lot more typing for every single property. :) Regarding `setPrototypeOf`, do you have an alternative mechanism to cause an element created by `DOMParser` to inherit new methods and properties?

Comment: @TachibanaShin Using `Object.setPrototypeOf` like this, right where you create the object, [doesn't actually make anything slow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23809148/1048572)

Comment: @Phrogz you can use constructor to directly access `Element` of newly created `DOM` without creating a class

Comment: @Bergi if you use setPrototypeOf it means that scxml's access cache is destroyed and the parts based on it. I bet `ValidityCell` is disabled now

Comment: @TachibanaShin Well the object was never part of any cache since it wasn't used anywhere before the prototype is changed…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems more elegant (less typing, more visually clear) to use classes

Nah, the main difference is not using `Object.defineProperties`. You can just use getter syntax in the object literal as well:

```
const SCXMLState = Object.setPrototypeOf({
  addChild() { },
  isState: true,
  get isSCXML: {
    return this.nodeName==='scxml';
  },
  get id() {
    return this.getAttribute('id') || (this.isSCXML ? '(scxml)' : null);
  },
}, Element.prototype);
```

Maybe not even use `Object.setPrototypeOf` but

```
const SCXMLState = {
  __proto__: Element.prototype,
  addChild() { },
  isState: true,
  get isSCXML: {
    return this.nodeName==='scxml';
  },
  get id() {
    return this.getAttribute('id') || (this.isSCXML ? '(scxml)' : null);
  },
};
```

I wouldn't use `class` syntax if you don't plan on using the constructor. (Though if you were [using custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements), you actually could).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `__proto__`, and I didn't know getter/method syntax was valid in a plain object. I clearly need to deep dive on the implementation of classes within the prototype system of JS. Care to followup on the negative implications of using `class` if all I care about is creating a prototype?

Comment: Not really negative - except you get a useless `.constructor` on your prototype.

Comment: Btw, `get`/`set` accessor syntax in object literals was introduced in ES5, way before classes :-)

Answer (score 0):

The following works, and is slightly more elegant than explicitly referencing the prototype each time when multiple inherited properties are desired. I'll happily accept a less clunky answer if one is presented.

```js
class SCXMLState extends Element {
   // …
}
Object.assign(SCXMLState.prototype, {
   isState: true,
   canHaveTransitions: true,
   // …
});
```