# Ember's notifyPropertyChange() does not fire observers of wrapped component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

This is a simplified example but demonstrates my problem well. I have an input for a PIN with buttons for digits (1, 2, 3, 4). The action on my buttons should set a property `pinValue` which is passed into the wrapped component `pin-input`. So this is what my code looks like:

**See example:**
http://ember-twiddle.com/38bd66b63e6745f2ea0d

**pin-entry.hbs**

```
{{pin-input pinValue=pinValue}}
{{#each numbers as |num|}}
    <button {{action "addNumber" num}}>{{num}}</button>
{{/each}}
```

**pin-entry.js**

```
pinValue: null,
numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4],
actions: {
    addNumber: function (number) {
        this.set('pinValue', number);
        this.notifyPropertyChange('pinValue');
    }
}
```

**pin-input.hbs**

```
<input type=text value={{value}}>
```

**pin-input.js**

```
value: null,
pinValue: null,

onInsertAddObserver: function() {
    // trying to manually subscribe to pinValue here.
    // * from stackOverflow answer
    var controller = this.get('targetObject');
    controller.addObserver('pinValue', this, this.onDataChange)
}.on('didInsertElement'),

onDidChangeInput: function() {
    var current = this.$('input').val();
    this.set('value', current + this.get('pinValue'));
}.observes('pinValue')
```

**The problem is when trying to input duplicate numbers back to back (e.g. 1233 will stop at 123).** I cannot seem to force a property change so that `onDidChangeInput` will fire. The `addObserver` method is from another post*.

*Some ideas taken from here but did not help me: [EmberJS notifyPropertyChange not making it to observer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25513056/emberjs-notifypropertychange-not-making-it-to-observer/25523850#25523850)

Comment: you don't need `notifyPropertyChange` or either of the observers.

Comment: Here's a working gist: http://ember-twiddle.com/9c1517b37f44635a17c7

Comment: The only issue is that glimmer will reset the cursor position after the value updates, you can fix that by using this component: http://ember-twiddle.com/2d7246875098d0dbb4a4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving it in with a simple, albeit inelegant, solution. For some reason, even if you pass a property into another component, changes in the main component's property don't cause observers in the wrapped component to fire if the value hasn't changed. Even if you call `notifyPropertyChange()` they still won't fire. The really simple solution I came up with is:

[See the twiddle here](https://ember-twiddle.com/38bd66b63e6745f2ea0d?numColumns=1) (just the important parts below)

**pin-entry.js**

```
pinValue: null,
_cachedValue: null,

actions: {
    addNumber: function (number) {
        this.set('pinValue', number);
        // just cache the value and if you detect a duplicate
        // then force the property to update
        if (this.get('_cachedValue') === number) {
            this.notifyPropertyChange('pinValue');
        }
        this.set('_cachedValue', number);
    }
}
```

**pin-input.js**

```
// this is how you have to subscribe.
onInsertAddObserver: function() {
    var c = this.get('targetObject');
    c.addObserver('pinValue', this, this._onChange)
}.on('didInsertElement'),
```

Anyone think this is way off?

Comment: Observers are bad practise in general, i provided u a decent solution but what the heck. Just to clarify why: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvZEddrClAQ

Comment: yeah, I use them sparingly, but they're not as evil as everyone says. I tried your example and it didn't work. If you plug your code into twiddle so I can see it working, then I'll mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Since data down and actions up

I would go with something like this.

```
{{pin-input pinCode=current}} // Explaining it later 
{{#each numbers as |num|}}
    {{pin-number nr=num numberChanged="numberChanged"}}
{{/each}}
```

*pin-number.js*

```
actions: {
    addNumber: function (number) {
        this.sendAction('numberChanged', number); // To the controller
    }
}
```

*controller.js*

```
   actions: {

     numberChanged: function(newNr) {
       var current = this.get('current');

       if(Ember.isNone(current) || current.length >= 4) { 
          this.set('current', newNr);
       } else {
          this.set('current', this.get('current') + "" + newNr);
       }

   }
```

And now we bind current to 
*pin-input*

```
{{pin-input pinCode=current}}
```