# Finding 'Key' in a JS Object based on 'Multiple Values'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Take the following cut down JS Object (JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52a4wq0x/1/) - emulating a multidimensional associative array I suppose.

```
var ControlMap = {
    tb_RosMon: { row: 1, col: 1 },
    tb_RosTue: { row: 1, col: 2 },
    tb_RosWed: { row: 1, col: 3 },
    tb_RosThu: { row: 1, col: 4 },
    tb_RosFri: { row: 1, col: 5 },
    tb_RosSat: { row: 1, col: 6 },
    tb_RosSun: { row: 1, col: 7 },

    tb_AbsMon: { row: 2, col: 1 },
    tb_AbsTue: { row: 2, col: 2 },
    tb_AbsWed: { row: 2, col: 3 },
    tb_AbsThu: { row: 2, col: 4 },
    tb_AbsFri: { row: 2, col: 5 },
    tb_AbsSat: { row: 2, col: 6 },
    tb_AbsSun: { row: 2, col: 7 },

    ddl_ReasonMon: { row: 3, col: 1 },
    ddl_ReasonTue: { row: 3, col: 2 },
    ddl_ReasonWed: { row: 3, col: 3 },
    ddl_ReasonThu: { row: 3, col: 4 },
    ddl_ReasonFri: { row: 3, col: 5 },
    ddl_ReasonSat: { row: 3, col: 6 },
    ddl_ReasonSun: { row: 3, col: 7 },

    tb_AddMon: { row: 4, col: 1 },
    tb_AddTue: { row: 4, col: 2 },
    tb_AddWed: { row: 4, col: 3 },
    tb_AddThu: { row: 4, col: 4 },
    tb_AddFri: { row: 4, col: 5 },
    tb_AddSat: { row: 4, col: 6 },
    tb_AddSun: { row: 4, col: 7 },

    Mon_AddReason: { row: 5, col: 1 },
    Tue_AddReason: { row: 5, col: 2 },
    Wed_AddReason: { row: 5, col: 3 },
    Thu_AddReason: { row: 5, col: 4 },
    Fri_AddReason: { row: 5, col: 5 },
    Sat_AddReason: { row: 5, col: 6 },
    Sun_AddReason: { row: 5, col: 7 }
}
```

This is basically a map of input id's (`tb_RosMon`, `tb_AbsMon` etc) and their row & column within an HTML `<table>.` I'm trying to add key navigation to the inputs in question (up, down, left & right).

i.e. if a user presses the down arrow whilst on `tb_AbsTue`, I fetch `tb_AbsTue`'s position as follows:

```
var row = ControlMap[SourceID]["row"]; //Returns 2
var col = ControlMap[SourceID]["col"]; //Returns 2
```

I'll then increment row by 1 (as they pressed down) to give me a destination of row 3 col 2. I then need to search the above object to see if an input (tb_###) exists at row 3 col 2 & return its ID.

How could one do that? Plain JS or JQuery would be fine.

Comment: I would seriously suggest rethinking that data structure, but if you're stuck with it then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907419/javascript-object-get-key-by-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.keys` and `some` would do it:

```
var id;
Object.keys(ControlMap).some(function(key) {
    var entry = ControlMap[key];
    if (entry.row == desiredRow && entry.col == desiredCol) {
        id = key;
        return true; // Stops the loop
    }
    return false;
});
```

Those are both ES5 features, but they're both polyfillable for IE8 and other older browsers. Alternately, you could just use `for-in`:

```
var id;
var key;
var entry;
for (key in ControlMap) {
    entry = ControlMap[key];
    if (entry.row == desiredRow && entry.col == desiredCol) {
        id = key;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly, I need to support IE7+ so i'll need to go the for-in route as you suggest. Thank you.

Comment: @HeavenCore: `Object.keys` and `Array#some` can both be polyfilled for IE7. But `for-in` works. :-)