# how to add click event to angular js directive for plotting flot bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, flot

I am pretty new to angularjs and flot charts. I am trying to add click events to my stacked bar charts so that once I click a stack it displays the categories information but I am not sure if am doing it right.
Please help take a look

I already plot my chart in angularjs directive

see http://jsfiddle.net/6h1gL2sh/10/ here

```
App.directive('chart', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        var chart = null,
            options = {
                series: {
                    stack: true,
                    bars: {
                        show: true,
                        clickable: true,
                        barWidth: 0.1,
                        align: "center"
                    }
                },
                axisLabels: {
                    show: true
                },

                xaxis: {
                    axisLabel: 'Products',
                    axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                    axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
                    axisLabelPadding: 5,
                    mode: "categories",
                    tickLength: 0
                },
                yaxis: {
                    axisLabel: 'Pass/Fail Count',
                    axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                    axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
                    axisLabelPadding: 5

                },
                grid: {
                    hoverable: true,
                    clickable: true
                }

            }
        var data = scope[attrs.ngModel];
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (v) {
            if (!chart) {
                chart = $.plot(elem, v, options);
                elem.show();
            } else {
                chart.setData(v);
                chart.setupGrid();
                chart.draw();
            }
        });
        $(elem).bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {
            scope.$apply(function () {
                if (item) {
                    scope.dis = item.series.xaxis.categories[item.dataIndex].label

                }
            });
        });

    }
};
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're trying to get an object's Key by value, you can't really access it as an array using bracket notation. I used a function that can be found on this SO question: [JavaScript object get key by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907419/javascript-object-get-key-by-value)

Then, I simply changed your click part to this:

```
elem.bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {  
      if(item){
            scope.dis= getKeyByValue(item.series.xaxis.categories, item.dataIndex);
            scope.$apply();
      }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6h1gL2sh/12/)

Comment: @Ese Great :) Please "accept" the answer that you find helpful, both for this post and future ones that you will have. This shows future visitors of this post what answer you found helpful and that solved your problem. To do that, just click on the empty tick mark under the rating of the answer (to the left of the answer) and that will turn into a green tick mark.