# How to add click event "plotclick" in angular flot pie char

Tags: jquery, angularjs, flot

I am using [angular-flot](https://github.com/develersrl/angular-flot/blob/master/angular-flot.js) to draw a pie chart. But I can't element plotclick. I tried:

```
element.bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {  
                if(item){
                    alert("Clicked");
                    scope.$apply();
               }
            });
```

But it is not being triggered.

This is my controller code:

```
$scope.dataset = [
          { label: "IE",  data: 19.5, color: "#4572A7"},
          { label: "Safari",  data: 4.5, color: "#80699B"},
          { label: "Firefox",  data: 36.6, color: "#AA4643"},
          { label: "Opera",  data: 2.3, color: "#3D96AE"},
          { label: "Chrome",  data: 36.3, color: "#89A54E"},
          { label: "Other",  data: 0.8, color: "#3D96AE"}
          ];
  $scope.options = {
    series: {
        pie: {
            show: true,
            radius: 1,
            label: {
                show: true,
                radius: 3/4,
                formatter: labelFormatter,
                background: {
                    opacity: 0.5,
                    color: '#000'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        show: false
    },

    grid: {
      hoverable: true,
      clickable: true
    }
```

So, do I have to change controller code or directive to implement click event.

Comment: Check my answer link. i think may helpful for u

Comment: It is a bit difficult to determine the context of the element variable.  Could you provide a JSFiddle example?

Answer (score 0):

click the link use it. may helpful for you
   [Click the Demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29587038/how-to-add-click-event-to-angular-js-directive-for-plotting-flot-bar-chart)