# Searching through a javascript enum

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript enum:

```
// Rooms
var rooms = {
 1: 'First Room',
 2: 'Second Room',
 3: 'Third Room',
};
```

I can easily get the room description as follows:

```
// Get Room Description
var roomOne = 1;
var roomdesc = rooms[roomOne];
```

How about if I have the room description 'First Room' and I want to get the room number?

I tried:

```
// Get room number
var roomIndex = rooms.indexOf('First Room');
var roomNum = rooms[roomIndex];
```

But indexOf is undefined.  How can I get the room number by room description?

Thanks

PS: Forgot to mention.  I cannot change the rooms object.  It is being used in other areas already!   Also, I would like to do this without using prototype or jquery. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var rooms = {
    1: 'First Room',
    2: 'Second Room',
    3: 'Third Room',
};

function test(val){
 for (var key in rooms) {
   if(rooms.hasOwnProperty(key))
    if (rooms[key] == val) {
        alert("Key:"+key);
    }
 }
}
test('First Room');//Pass the value you want to search for
```

Comment: You need to check `rooms.hasOwnProperty(key)` to assure you're accessing the correct object properties.

Comment: @RobertSmith. Forgot that part, updated thanks :) Robert Great :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Array's for this purposes:

```js
var rooms = ['First Room','Second Room','Third Room'];
// Get Room Description
var roomOne = 0;
var roomdesc = rooms[roomOne];
// Get room number
var roomIndex = rooms.indexOf('First Room');
var roomNum = rooms[roomIndex];

console.log( roomNum )
```

Not that Arrays are zero-first indexed.

Comment: Thanks but, Sorry forgot to mention the rooms object cannot be changed.  It is already being used in other places.

Comment: @RobertSmith but you can iterate over it anyway, do you?

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
var test = {
    1: 'First Room',
    2: 'Second Room',
    3: 'Third Room',
};
function getKeyByValue (obj, value) {
    for( var prop in obj ) {
        if( obj.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
             if( obj[ prop ] === value )
                 return prop;
        }
    }
}
console.log(getKeyByValue( test, "Second Room" ));  // logs 2
```

Comment: Copying an answer from another question is not really constructive.

Comment: What is the purpose to copy-paste answers from [other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907419/javascript-object-get-key-by-value) rather than writing your own or point to that answers?

Comment: Thanks, but is there a simpler 2 or 3 line solution without using Object.prototype?

Comment: Well you can simply write a for loop on the Object, check if it hasOwnProperty and return the value. (Updated answer)