# Get corresponding key from value in angular/js in key/value object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

is there any easy way to get the key from the key/value object, if I know the value?

For example I know that value is "red" in these data:

```
1: 'red',
2: 'blue',
3: 'yellow'
```

And I want to be able to track number 1 with that.
I am looking for the solution without the loops over an object, to be more exact, I would like to know if there is something like the vice-versa solution like this:

```
var nameOfColor = colors[1];
```

Or is there no such way? Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Why don't you use `array` ?

Comment: For any object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907419/javascript-object-get-key-by-value
For an array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, by using **Object.keys()** method and **.filter()** method.

```
  var obj = {
    1: 'red',
    2: 'blue'
  }

  Object.prototype.getKey = function(value) {
    var self = this;
    //Retrieve all key of current object
    return Object.keys(self).filter(function(elm){
      //Then, if current object get current key
      return self.hasOwnProperty(elm)
      //true if value are equals
      ? self[elm] === value
      //Otherwise false
      : false;
    });
  }

  console.log(obj.getKey('red'));
```