# How to check for value in javascript object?

Tags: javascript, object, associative-array

I do have a javscript object containing a product name and the corresponding product code. The code is unique.

```
var products = {
"Pineapple":38,
"Apple":110,
"Pear":109
};
```

If i want to know the code for a product i can just do

```
var pineapplecode = products["Pineapple"];
```

How do I check if there is a product for a given number and if print it ? Or do I have to/should I change the way the data is saved ?

Comment: There is no key as `product` in given object..

Comment: You'd have to loop through all the properties looking for the code value. You could have *two* objects, one mapping from name to code and the other mapping from code to name.

Answer (score 1):

I think the shortest way would be:

```
var prodCode = 38;
var result = Object.keys(products)
                   .filter(function(k) { return products[k] == prodCode; })[0];

// result == "Pineapple"
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: product code should be unique, i assume.

Comment: @NinaScholz, I assume so as well. That's why I'm only returning `[0]`, assuming it's the only one that found.

Comment: but then no need to iterate over all elements.

Comment: @NinaScholz, I guess you're right. That's the downside of using `filter()` (although negligible for most cases). There is the new (ES6) `find()` method that would do just that - find the first one that matches and return immediately (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Comment: @haim770 That answer is also in the thread I marked as a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907419/javascript-object-get-key-by-value

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are basically asking if I can check the other way round, i.e. check for key by passing value.

Yes you can,

- Either by iterating through all the key and values, check if the value is existing and finally return the key if the value exists
- change the way you save the data, index it by product number rather than product name

here is the code to convert one form to another

```
var newProducts = {};
for( var prodName in products )
{
  newProducts[ products[ prodName ] ] = prodName;
}
console.log( newProducts );
```

And here is the code to check a specific value

```
var valueToCheck = "110";
var prodNameToFind = "";
for( var prodName in products )
{
  if ( products[ prodName ] == valueToCheck )
  {
      prodNameToFind = prodName;  
  }
}
console.log( prodNameToFind );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the keys and the properties values and break the iteration if found with [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

> The `some()` method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
var products = {
        Pineapple: 38,
        Apple: 110,
        Pear: 109
    };

function getProduct(code) {
    var product;
    Object.keys(products).some(function (k) {
        if (products[k] === code) {
            product = k;
            return true;
        }          
    });
    return product;
}
document.write(getProduct(109));
```