# AngularJS way to grab a value by another value from the object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, object, filter

What's the AngularJS way to get the value by key from the object?

```
var myobj=   {
        "set1": {
            "key": "B11",
            "color": "yellow"
        },
        "setA": {
            "key": "F34",
            "color": "green"
        }
    }
```

let's say I'd like to grab `"green"` from `myobj` by `"F34"`? (myobj could be any number of objects).

Can it be done by an AngularJS way or I have to take a look into [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907419/javascript-object-get-key-by-value)

Comment: It's a general JS problem, not specific to Angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're planning on using this scenario in multiple controllers / services I'd create a custom filter to do the work for me.

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('getColour', getColour);

function getColour() {
    return filter;

    function filter(object, key) {
        var colour;
        angular.forEach(object, function(set) {
            if (set.key === key)
                colour = set.color;
        });

        return colour;
    }
}
```

This can then be used like this:

```
$scope.colour = $filter('getColour')(myobj, 'F34');
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3833/)