# Is it possible to extract Specific Values from the mentioned JSON?

Tags: jquery

The response for below Rest API call is

http://techpaisa.com/supres/m&m/

```
{
    "s": "M&M",
    "c": 1300.2,
    "e": false,
    "d": "20 March 2017",
    "l": [
        [1508.95, "52 Week High"],
        [1361.0, "Fibonacci Retracement Resisance"],
        [1360.0, "Call Option with Maximum Open Interest"],
        [1332.3500000000001, "R3 (Pivot Point)"],
        [1331.5685000000003, "200-Day Simple Moving Average"],
        [1326.8818166890858, "Average True Range (Upper Level)"],
        [1324.4000000000001, "R2 (Pivot Point)"],
        [1314.8699999999994, "20-Day Simple Moving Average"],
        [1312.3000000000002, "R1 (Pivot Point)"],
        [1307.73139784, "20-Day Exponential Moving Average"],
        [1304.3500000000001, "Pivot"],
        [1300.2, "Previous Closing Price (CP)"],
        [1300.0, "Put Option with Maximum Open Interest"],
        [1292.82354169, "200-Day Exponential Moving Average"],
        [1292.2500000000002, "S1 (Pivot Point)"],
        [1290.8456999999999, "Fibonacci Retracement (38% Level)"],
        [1284.7771330400001, "50-Day Exponential Moving Average"],
        [1284.3000000000002, "S2 (Pivot Point)"],
        [1273.5181833109143, "Average True Range (Lower Level)"],
        [1273.4080000000001, "50-Day Simple Moving Average"],
        [1272.2000000000003, "S3 (Pivot Point)"],
        [1269.175, "Fibonacci Retracement (50% Level)"],
        [1247.5043000000001, "Fibonacci Retracement (61% Level)"],
        [1177.3499999999999, "Fibonacci Retracement Support"],
        [1141.4000000000001, "52 Week Low"]
    ]
}
```

I am trying to extract Support  values for a Stock

```
var symbol = jsonRes.s;   // Symbol
```

Is it possible to extract these values (Support) from the above JSON ??

**S1 (Pivot Point) , S2 (Pivot Point) , S3 (Pivot Point)**

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/467/

Comment: dont' know key name but the values will be always fixed like  S3 (Pivot Point)  , S2 (Pivot Point) , S1 (Pivot Point)

Comment: how can i define that those 3 are support values? means you need to extract some set of values from the given json??

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907419/javascript-object-get-key-by-value

Answer (score 2):

statically we can find out.

```
 var ll = jsonRes.l;
 var s1 = ll[14];
 var s2 = ll[17];
 var s3 = ll[20];
console.log(s1[1])
console.log(s2[1])
console.log(s3[1])
```

webapi result is constant we can do as above.

Comment: thanks but this service is constantly changing the values

Comment: sorry for late.then you need to find the element with your fields then get the values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `startsWith()` & `endsWith()` method like following.

```js
var jsonRes = {
    "s": "M&M",
    "c": 1300.2,
    "e": false,
    "d": "20 March 2017",
    "l": [
        [1508.95, "52 Week High"],
        [1361.0, "Fibonacci Retracement Resisance"],
        [1360.0, "Call Option with Maximum Open Interest"],
        [1332.3500000000001, "R3 (Pivot Point)"],
        [1331.5685000000003, "200-Day Simple Moving Average"],
        [1326.8818166890858, "Average True Range (Upper Level)"],
        [1324.4000000000001, "R2 (Pivot Point)"],
        [1314.8699999999994, "20-Day Simple Moving Average"],
        [1312.3000000000002, "R1 (Pivot Point)"],
        [1307.73139784, "20-Day Exponential Moving Average"],
        [1304.3500000000001, "Pivot"],
        [1300.2, "Previous Closing Price (CP)"],
        [1300.0, "Put Option with Maximum Open Interest"],
        [1292.82354169, "200-Day Exponential Moving Average"],
        [1292.2500000000002, "S1 (Pivot Point)"],
        [1290.8456999999999, "Fibonacci Retracement (38% Level)"],
        [1284.7771330400001, "50-Day Exponential Moving Average"],
        [1284.3000000000002, "S2 (Pivot Point)"],
        [1273.5181833109143, "Average True Range (Lower Level)"],
        [1273.4080000000001, "50-Day Simple Moving Average"],
        [1272.2000000000003, "S3 (Pivot Point)"],
        [1269.175, "Fibonacci Retracement (50% Level)"],
        [1247.5043000000001, "Fibonacci Retracement (61% Level)"],
        [1177.3499999999999, "Fibonacci Retracement Support"],
        [1141.4000000000001, "52 Week Low"]
    ]
};

var support=[];
jsonRes.l.forEach(function(item){
    var text = item[1];
    if(text.startsWith('S') && text.endsWith('(Pivot Point)'))
        support.push({value: item[0], text: item[1]});
});
console.log(support);
```

Comment: Values mean `1292.2500000000002` and so on? @Pawan

Comment: How you want this? i.e. `{value: 1292.2500000000002, text: 'S1 (Pivot Point)'}` @Pawan

Comment: Sorry for the dealy , that will be great if u can help me out.