# Using local json file to lookup key:value using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a state-abbreviation json file from [here](https://gist.github.com/mshafrir/2646763). In my .js file, I have var=state that I want to look up the abbreviation for. So I need help in finding how to do that. For example lookup state (=Maine) in the json to get the "ME" value.
Please help!
Newbie in javascript so please please be as basic as possible in your answer. 
Thanks

**Update**
So my json is fine. Here is a sample from it...

```
[{"Alabama": "AL","Alaska": "AK","American Samoa": "AS",.....})
```

In my .js file, I am 'trying' to get the json file and use it for lookup like so. Obviously this isn't working. I know there are many mistakes so please be nice when helping out. Remember I am a newbie. ;-)

```
$.getJSON("/files/json/states_hash.json", function(json){
var data = eval("(" + json.responseText +")");
var val=_.findValue(json, stateNameVar);
console.log(json);
});
```

Comment: Why don't you invert (using a simple script) your json? That means you create a new json where the key is "Maine" and the value is "ME"... for example: `var new_json = Object.keys(your_json).reduce(function(obj, key){ obj[your_json[key] ] = key;  return obj; }, {});`

Comment: What do you mean by 'local'? You can't read files from the filesystem with JavaScript without user input.

Comment: Do you need full explanation starting from "how to get json from server", or just a way to lookup for the value ?

Comment: @Jared He probably means "server-side".

Comment: The first thing to know when handling JSON in JavaScript is that it means JavaScript Object Notation, and that you should simply be handling objects rather than their text/json representation. You can transform from and to JSON with a process called (de)serialization (or sometimes (un)marshalling)

Answer (score 2):

Building upon Matteo's comment, an option is to run a simple one-time script to reverse the keys/values. This makes the lookups you're trying to do fairly trivial:

```js
// here's what you have now:
const states = { 'VA': 'Virginia', 'CO': 'Colorado' };
console.log(states);

// this flips the keys/values:
const flippedStates = {};
Object.entries(states).forEach(([k,v]) => { flippedStates[v] = k })
console.log(flippedStates);

// lookup by full name:
console.log(flippedStates['Virginia']);
console.log(flippedStates['Colorado']);
```

Weave in `JSON.parse`/`stringify` where needed.

Answer (score 0):

Since the abbreviation in this case is the key, you'll want to use an appropriate method to find a key by its value. That will depend on what you have available to you. Several methods of doing as such can be found here: [JavaScript object get key by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907419/javascript-object-get-key-by-value)

Now, you'll also have to load the JSON into the page. Again, this depends on your environment (node.js, in browser, etc.). With node.js it'd be as simple as `const states = require("./states.json");`, but in browser there are several different methods with different trade offs that are better described here: [Loading local JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file)

Comment: A link to an answer is not an answer. Explain here why the links are relevant and how they can help the OP.

Comment: Updated to give a little more context to the links, although this question is still a little ambiguous so it's hard to give a direct answer.

Comment: If your answer is a link to another answer, you should just click the "flag" button under the question and flag it as a duplicate question.

Comment: In this case, it was a combination of two answers which required some level of synthesis.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question you are trying to invert the key / value relation of a Json. You can  simply invert it programmatically with something like that **may be** the more efficient things to do:

```
var data = { /*your json */ }
var newData = Object.keys(data).reduce(function(obj,key){
  obj[ data[key] ] = key;
  return obj;
},{});
```

OR without using external libraries (it is not too much efficient):

```
function getKeyByValue(data, state) {
  return Object.keys(data).find(key => data[key] === state);
}
```

OR you can use external libraries. It is up to you.

#### From your code:

I've put on Gist a JSON like the one that you are using
You can test this code below... (Sorry but due to CORS policy I have to insert this very long address to the Gist).

```js
var json_file = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/MatteoRagni/71280e5be2281347d915f90a60b7167b/raw/f3cf77fb2755461be96d03023226220583d6939d/state2_hash.json";
var state = "Maine";

$.getJSON(json_file, function(json) {
  console.log(json[state]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I shouldn't need to invert anything since my json is the way i need it to be with the state-name as the key and the state-abbreviation as the value. Right? So in my console I see that the variable **json** is picking up my file after the first line. $.getJSON("/rinlocator/json/states_hash.json", function(json){...

So is there a way to do something like var stateAbbreviation = json.lookup(stateName)

Comment: You are meaning something like `json["Alabama"]` to get `"AL"`? or `json.Alabama` even works...

Comment: Below is my method. Chrome debugger shows me state1="Maine" but val is undefined! Why isn't val getting the "ME" value that it should?

    $.getJSON("/files/json/states_hash.json", function(json){
    var val = json[state1];
    console.log(val);
    });

Comment: try this: `$.getJSON("/files/json/states_hash.json", function(json){ var val = json[state1]; console.log(val); conole.log(state1); });`. does it prints "undefined \n Maine"?

Comment: Yes it does. I need it to print undefined \n ME instead

Comment: Check the answer again, please.

Comment: I am looking at it right now. Its the same. For some reason the lookup function isn't working. So it means there is something with the lookup function?  I did this console.log(json) and that prints an object with all the states-abbreviations.
[Object]
0
:
Object
Alabama
:
"AL"
Alaska
:
"AK"
American Samoa
:
"AS"
Arizona
:
"AZ"

Comment: Ah! Your json is inside an Array?? try `console.log(json[0][state]);`

Comment: Yes!!!! Thank you so much. That worked. I don't know how to mark this as the correct answer.