# How to iterate over JSONObject and found id by value which already known, for example I want to get id of value "ТС-41" how can I do it?

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, iteration

```
{
"0":"",
"54049":"ОП.мз-61а",
"100606":"КМ-41",
"100609":"МТ-41",
"100612":"ЕМ-41",
"100684":"ХК-51",
"100685":"ЕМ-51",
"100687":"КМ-51",
"100688":"МТ-51",
"100718":"ХК-51/1",
"100719":"ХК-51/2",
"100748":"ТС-61",
"100749":"ТС-61/1",
"100750":"ТС-61/2",
"100754":"ЕМ-61",
"100758":"ІМ-61/1МБ",
"100759":"ІМ-61/2ГТ",
"100760":"МБ-61",
"100767":"ТС-51",
"100770":"ТС-41",
"100777":"ТС.м-61",
"100778":"МТ.м-61",
"100779":"ЕМ.м-61",
"100780":"ТМ.м-61",
"100781":"ТМ.м-62",
"100782":"ГМ.м-61",
"100783":"ВІ.м-61",
"100786":"ХМ.м-61"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript object get key by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907419/javascript-object-get-key-by-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to iterate over the JSONObject keys and compare the value until a match.

```
final String knownValue = "TC-41";
final Iterator<String> iterable = jsonObject.keys();
while (iterable.hasNext()) {
    String key = iterable.next();
    if (jsonObject.getString(key).equals(knownValue)) {
        // key has the value you are looking for
       return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON Classes for parsing

```
JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(Your_Sring_data);

String id = mainObject .getString("100770");

 //here in this **id** string you can get value for **"TC-41"**
```

Comment: In the same way you can get all the values in respective strings