# Get TypeScript enum name from instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, enums

I have the following TypeScript enum:

```
enum Country {
    BR = "Brazil",
    NO = "Norway"
}
```

Then imagine I have a method that takes a `Country` as an argument, like so:

```
someFunc = (country: Country): void => {
    console.log(country) //Will print "Brazil" if country = Country.BR
    console.log(Country[country]) //Same as above
    console.log(???) //I want to print "BR" if country = Country.BR
}
```

How do I solve the third `console.log` statement?

How do I get a hold of the enum key?

Regards

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Under the enum constrution you get something like this

```
Country["BR"] = "Brazil";
Country["NO"] = "Norway";
```

which is a simple object.

By default you can't get the keys of your enum. But you can iterate over the keys manually and try to find that one.

```
enum Country {
    BR = "Brazil",
    NO = "Norway"
}

console.log(Object.keys(Country).find(key => Country[key] === country))
```

Comment: But that means making an if statement for all possible values?

Comment: Why if statements? You can just compare with your country

Comment: It's not very flexible... Say I have 100 enum values inside my `Country` enum, and my method would like to print the country code (key of the enum) for a given enum instance. Then there's no solution for this?

Comment: `Country[key] === country)` this statement will work for every country. It just gets the key of that enum. If I understood you correct.

Comment: Ah yes, that works indeed! Was hoping there was a more simple solution for this

Answer (score 4):

`ts-enum-util` ([github](https://github.com/UselessPickles/ts-enum-util), [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-enum-util)) supports reverse lookup of value->key for string enums, compile time type safety, and run-time validation.

```
import {$enum} from "ts-enum-util";

enum Country {
    BR = "Brazil",
    NO = "Norway"
}

someFunc = (country: Country): void => {
    // throws an error if the value of "country" at run time is
    // not "Brazil" or "Norway".  
    // type of "name": ("BR" | "NO")
    const name = $enum(Country).getKeyOrThrow(country);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand what is the js code for

```
enum Country {
    BR = "brazil",
    NO = "norway"
}
```

Its simply

```
var Country;
(function (Country) {
    Country["BR"] = "brazil";
    Country["NO"] = "norway";
})(Country || (Country = {}));
```

So basically it's an object with "BR" and "NO" as keys.
and assuming we know how to find key from value in object. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28191966/2906821)  .
Using same

```
enum Country {
    BR = "brazil",
    NO = "norway"
}

namespace Country {
    export function getEnum(c: string): Country | undefined {
        if(!c) return undefined;
        const cLowerCase = c.toLowerCase();
        return Object.keys(Country).find(k => Country[k as keyof typeof Country] === cLowerCase) as Country
    }
}


console.log(Country.getEnum('test'))

console.log(Country.getEnum('Brazil'))

console.log(Country.getEnum('norway'))
```

If you are wondering why we used `keyof typeof` check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62764510/2906821)

In case you have lots of keys in enum you can use map to store reverse mapping and use that

Answer (score 0):

I made this "generic" version

```js
enum AccountType {
  Google = 'goo',
  Local = 'cal',
  Facebook = 'boo',
  Twitter = 'x',
  LinkedIn = 'ink'
}

function getEnumName<T> (enumType: Record<string, number|string>, value: T) {
  return Object.entries(enumType).find(([k,v] ) =>  v === value )?.[0];
}
 
console.log(getEnumName(AccountType, AccountType.Twitter));
```

Answer (score -1):

I often use a plain JavaScript object instead of an enum, and use the `keyof` operator for type safety on its keys:

```
const CountryMap = {
    BR: "Brazil",
    NO: "Norway"
};

// equivalent to: type Country = 'BR' | 'NO';
type Country = keyof typeof CountryMap;

const someFunc = (country: Country): void => {
    console.log(country);
}
```