# What does "keyof typeof" mean in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typeof, union-types, keyof

Explain to me what `keyof typeof` means in TypeScript

Example:

```
enum ColorsEnum {
    white = '#ffffff',
    black = '#000000',
}

type Colors = keyof typeof ColorsEnum;
```

The last row is equivalent to:

```
type Colors = "white" | "black"
```

But how does it work?

I would expect `typeof ColorsEnum` to return something like `"Object"` and then `keyof "Object"` to not do anything interesting. But I am obviously wrong.

Comment: typeof during "compile time" is different from JS's typeof during runtime...

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`keyof` takes an object type and returns a type that accepts any of the object's keys.

```js
type Point = { x: number; y: number };
type P = keyof Point; // type '"x" || "y"'

const coordinate: P = 'z' // Type '"z"' is not assignable to type '"x" | "y"'.
```

### typeof with TypeScript types

`typeof` behaves differently when called on javascript objects, to when it is called on typescript types.

- TypeScript uses [javascript's typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) when called on javascript values at runtime and returns one of `"undefined", "object", "boolean", "number", "bigint", "string", "symbol", "function"`
- [TypeScript's typeof](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) is called on type values, but can also be called on javascript values when in a type expression. It can also infer the type of javascript objects, returning a more detailed object type.

```js
type Language = 'EN' | 'ES'; 
const userLanguage: Language = 'EN';
const preferences = { language: userLanguage, theme: 'light' };

console.log(typeof preferences); // "object"
type Preferences = typeof preferences; // type '{language: 'EN''; theme: string; }'
```

Because the second `typeof preferences` is in a type expression it is actually TypeScript's own `typeof` that get called, and not javascript's.

### keyof typeof

Because [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) is a TypeScript concept we will be calling TypeScript's verion of `typeof`.

`keyof typeof` will infer the type of a javascript object and return a type that is the union of its keys. Because it can infer the exact value of the keys it can return a union of their [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html) instead of just returning "string".

```js
type PreferenceKeys = keyof typeof preferences; // type '"language" | "theme"'
```

Answer (score 863):

To understand the `keyof typeof` usage in TypeScript, first you need to understand what are **literal types** and **union of literal types**. So, I'll explain these concepts first and then explain `keyof` and `typeof` individually in detail. After that, I'll come back to `enum` to answer what is asked in the question. It's a long answer but examples are easy to understand.

---

### Literal types

Literal types in TypeScript are more specific types of `string`, `number` or `boolean`. For example, `"Hello World"` is a `string`, but a `string` is not `"Hello World"`. `"Hello World"` is a more specific type of type `string`, so it is a literal type.

A literal type can be declared as following:

```
type Greeting = "Hello"
```

This means that the object of type `Greeting` can have only a `string` value `"Hello"` and no other `string` value or any other value of any other type as shown in the following code:

```
let greeting: Greeting
greeting = "Hello" // OK
greeting = "Hi"    // Error: Type '"Hi"' is not assignable to type '"Hello"'
```

Literal types are not useful on their own, however when combined with union types, type aliases and type guards they become powerful.

Following is an example of **union of literal types**:

```
type Greeting = "Hello" | "Hi" | "Welcome"
```

Now the object of type `Greeting` can have the value either `"Hello"`, `"Hi"` or `"Welcome"`.

```
let greeting: Greeting
greeting = "Hello"       // OK
greeting = "Hi"          // OK
greeting = "Welcome"     // OK
greeting = "GoodEvening" // Error: Type '"GoodEvening"' is not assignable to type 'Greeting'
```

---

### `keyof` only

`keyof` of some type `T` gives you a new type that is a **union of literal types** and these literal types are the names of the properties of `T`. The resulting type is a subtype of string.

For example, consider the following `interface`:

```
interface Person {
    name: string
    age: number
    location: string
}
```

Using the `keyof` operator on the type `Person` will give you a new type as shown in the following code:

```
type SomeNewType = keyof Person
```

This `SomeNewType` is a union of literal types (`"name" | "age" | "location"`) that is made from the properties of type `Person`.

Now you can create objects of type `SomeNewType`:

```
let newTypeObject: SomeNewType
newTypeObject = "name"           // OK
newTypeObject = "age"            // OK
newTypeObject = "location"       // OK
newTypeObject = "anyOtherValue"  // Error...
```

---

### `keyof typeof` together on an object

As you might already know, the `typeof` operator gives you the type of an object.
In the above example of `Person` interface, we already knew the type, so we just had to use the `keyof` operator on type `Person`.

But what to do when we don't know the type of an object or we just have a value and not a type of that value like the following?

```
const bmw = { name: "BMW", power: "1000hp" }
```

This is where we use `keyof typeof` together.

The `typeof bmw` gives you the type: `{ name: string, power: string }`

And then `keyof` operator gives you the literal type union as shown in the following code:

```
type CarLiteralType = keyof typeof bmw

let carPropertyLiteral: CarLiteralType
carPropertyLiteral = "name"       // OK
carPropertyLiteral = "power"      // OK
carPropertyLiteral = "anyOther"   // Error...
```

---

### `keyof typeof` on an `enum`

In TypeScript, enums are used as *types at compile-time* to achieve type-safety for the constants but they are treated as *objects at runtime*. This is because, they are converted to plain objects once the TypeScript code is compiled to JavaScript. So, the explanation of the objects above is applicable here too. The example given by OP in the question is:

```
enum ColorsEnum {
    white = '#ffffff',
    black = '#000000',
}
```

Here `ColorsEnum` exists as an object at runtime, not as a type. So, we need to invoke `keyof typeof` operators together as shown in the following code:

```
type Colors = keyof typeof ColorsEnum

let colorLiteral: Colors
colorLiteral = "white"  // OK
colorLiteral = "black"  // OK
colorLiteral = "red"    // Error...
```

Answer (score 37):

An `enum` creates an instantiated `object`. With `typeof` we get the auto generated type of this `enum`.

Now we can get all indices with `keyof` to make sure `Colors` can only contain one of them.

Answer (score 19):

**Common misconception about TypeScript**

TypeScript is often described as a type layer on top of JavaScript runtime. As if types and values lived on separate planes. However, in TypeScript, some things are types *and* values at the same time.

This is true for:

- classes,
- enums,
- namespaces.

**When can you use `keyof`?**

The `keyof` keyword only works on the type level. You cannot apply it to a JavaScript value.

**When do you need `keyof typeof`?**

When you're dealing with something that is a type and a value at the same time (like a class or an enum), but you're interested specifically in what the type of that value is.

The simplest example:

```
const foo = { bar: 42 }; // foo is a value
type Foo = typeof foo; // Foo is the type of foo

type KeyOfFoo = keyof Foo; // "keyof Foo" is the same as "keyof typeof foo", which is "bar"
```

In general, when you see this:

```
type A = keyof typeof B;
```

the `typeof B` part tells TypeScript to look at the *type* of B. You can think of it as casting B to its type. Sort of like casting a two-dimensional object to a one-dimensional space.

Since `typeof B` is a type, not a value, we can now use `keyof` on it.

**Example**

Classes are types and values. You can call them, but you can also use `keyof` on them.

```
declare class Foo {
    static staticProperty: string;

    dynamicProperty: string;
}

type Constructor = typeof Foo;
type Instance = Foo;

type A = keyof Constructor; // "prototype" | "staticProperty"
type B = keyof Instance; // "dynamicProperty"
```

By using `typeof` together with `keyof`, we can toggle between using `keyof` against the *instance* type and the *constructor* type.

Answer (score 2):

For finding the type of any values we use typeof operation. For eg

```
const user = {
   getPersonalInfo(){},
   getLocation(){}
}
```

Here user is a value so here typeof operator comes in handy

```
type userType = typeof user
```

Here userType gives type information that user is an object which have two properties getPersonalInfo and getLocation and both are functions return void

Now if you want to find the keys of user you can use keyof

```
type userKeys = keyof userType
```

which says userKeys= **'getPersonalInfo'| 'getLocation'**

> Beware if you try to get user's key like `type userKeys = keyof user` you will get an error ***'user' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof user'?***