# How does keyof typeof generic constraint work?

Tags: typescript

[What does "keyof typeof" mean in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55377365/10694438)

I found the above question where the writer asked exactly the same thing I want to ask, but no answer has found the point of the question.

Let's say there is this generic method and a class.

```
function fn<K extends keyof typeof A>(key: K) ...

class A {
    static a;
    static b;
}
```

My reasoning is:

1. typeof keyword returns a string that shows one of the js basic types.
2. So no matter what the value is, the return type is string.
3. So keyof "..." should be the indices and "length" and stuff that the string literal can have. In this case, keyof "function" should return type "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "length".
4. But the actual behavior is that typeof class A returns the constructor.

How could this happen?

Comment: *"typeof keyword returns a string that shows one of the js basic types."* False, `typeof` has a different meaning in this context in Typescript. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/types-from-extraction.html#the-typeof-type-operator

Comment: Not knowing a lot of typescript I find the answers on the linked-to question to be *very* informative. And even if the style of one of them is not to your liking, there's multiple answers that seem to be good so you can read multiple and pick the one that helps you most. I vote to close, because I think this is strictly a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "keyof typeof" mean in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377365/what-does-keyof-typeof-mean-in-typescript)

Comment: @JoachimSauer Of course not in that I referred to the question at the top of my question. There are no source of the behavior in answers in the question. The question and mine want the source as well as the fact that typeof can mean multiple things as we'd already known the behavior.

Comment: @kaya3 Thank you so much. I'd select your answer if you post it with that. Your comment is actually the real answer that I wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> typeof keyword returns a string that shows one of the js basic types.

This is true for JavaScript, but in Typescript, `typeof` can mean multiple things, depending on the context. Unlike in JS, in TS, when `typeof` is in a context where a *type* is expected, `typeof expression` will evaluate to the (TypeScript-determined) type of `expression`. For example:

```
let num = 5;
type Num = typeof num;
```

results in the `Num` type being `number`. This is not the *string* `'number'` - it is the TypeScript Type `number`.

So, in your code:

```
function fn<K extends keyof typeof A>(key: K) ...
```

Since `K extends keyof ...` is a *type* context (which is useful for configuring TypeScript's interpretation of the code, but does not exist in the emitted JavaScript), the following `typeof` indicates to TypeScript to substitute `typeof A` with the TypeScript-detected type that A is.

In contrast, when *not* in a type context:

```
let someStr = 'foo';
const theType = typeof someStr;
```

Here, `typeof` is being used in *runtime JavaScript*, in the emitted code, rather than as TypeScript-specific syntax, so it results in `theType` being assigned the value `'string'` at runtime.

The two ways that `typeof` can be used are entirely different.