# How to access Enum in typescript ? giving error "Element implicitly has an any type because index expression is not of type number"

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, enums

```
export enum r {
  color1 = "Red"
  color2 = "green"
  color3 = "blue"
}

ar = ["color1", "color2"];
ar.map(e => {
  if (r[e as any] !== undefined) {
    return r[e]
  }
})
```

Above statement giving "Element implicitly has an any type because index expression is not of type number"

Answer (score 7):

You need to type `ar` with `keyof typeof` to let TypeScript know your array contains keys from your enum:

```
export enum r {
  color1 = "Red",
  color2 = "green",
  color3 = "blue",
}

const ar: (keyof typeof r)[] = ["color1", "color2"];
const newVal = ar.map((e) => {
  if (r[e] !== undefined) {
    return r[e];
  }
});
```

Here is a good in-depth [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377365/what-does-keyof-typeof-mean-in-typescript) about it

Answer (score 2):

You do not have commas after every item in your enum. However, the following is how you can typecast the argument to be type of key of the enum:

```
export enum r {
color1 = "Red",
color2 = "green",
color3 = "blue",
}

const ar = ["color1","color2"];
const new_ar = ar.filter(e => {
    if (e in r && r[e as keyof typeof r]) 
    {return true;}
    else {return false;}
})
```

The problem with your approach is you are using map and you need to return in every iteration. What you need is filter.