# Convert enum structure value:key to key:value in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, enumerable

I'm trying convert a enum structur from [key:value] with value as string to [value:key] structure with this code.

my error is

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number | "toString" | "charAt" | "charCodeAt" | "concat" | "indexOf" | "lastIndexOf" | "localeCompare" | "match" | "replace" | "search" | "slice" | "split" | "substring" | "toLowerCase" | ... 31 more ... | "trimEnd"' can't be used to index type 'typeof Country'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type 'typeof Country'
```

> key as keyof Country

**enumeral**

```
export enum Country {
    UnitedStates = 'US',
    Afghanistan = 'AF',
    AlandIslands = 'AX',
    }
```

**code**

```
 public countries = Object.keys(Country)
  .slice(Object.keys(Country).length / 2)
  .map(key => ({
    label: key,
    key: Country[key as keyof Country],
  }));
```

when value of enum is *int* this code works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you cast to the wrong type

Here is a [typescript playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9mEAXATgTygbwLACgpQCqIAlksACYDKSAhuQM5QC8UARIVWwDR4ECCAMwDmAC1qkGdEC3b8AYjz5R%20AGwkUAkg3UgKTVm34ANNngC%20ePEjQAHYFAAqAaWBoDUANZu4g2AmR0AG5rOwdHAFFwCFd3WW80XygbeyT4RFQ0ENw8AGM4ECkoOFskEgKPAHkAIwArYFykADoEhgAKdMC0AEo8JohaWzaElgA%20KDacfC83Xmn1auBVAC5-DPQAbRHaJgSklOA0gMyAXSgLbu7s-MK4VWAm1ThhNpKyiqu8IA)

`keyof Country` includes all keys of the Country enum object - just hoover overt `TKeys` in the example to see the list

What you actually want is: `Country[key as keyof typeof Country]`
`keyof typeof Country` is the type of all enum keys: `"UnitedStates" | "Afghanistan" | "AlandIslands"`
Hoover over `TEnumKeys` in the example.

To understand the difference, check this question: [What does “keyof typeof” mean in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377365/what-does-keyof-typeof-mean-in-typescript)