# How to specify type of index of enum in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider the following example:

```
enum Color {
    Green = "green",
    Red = "red"

}

let index : keyof Color
index = "Green" 

console.log(Color[index])
```

Error

```
Type '"Green"' is not assignable to type 'number | "toString" | "charAt" | "charCodeAt" | "concat" | "indexOf" | "lastIndexOf" | "localeCompare" | "match" | "replace" | "search" | "slice" | "split" | "substring" | "toLowerCase" | ... 27 more ... | "padEnd"'.
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number | "toString" | "charAt" | "charCodeAt" | "concat" | "indexOf" | "lastIndexOf" | "localeCompare" | "match" | "replace" | "search" | "slice" | "split" | "substring" | "toLowerCase" | ... 27 more ... | "padEnd"' can't be used to index type 'typeof Color'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type 'typeof Color'.
```

The index variable has to be string version of keys of enum Color.
How do I specify the type of index variable?

Comment: Maybe: `let index : keyof typeof Color`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `let index: keyof typeof Color`, because `Color` is actually an object (a dictionary of sorts), so you will need to get its type first using `typeof`. For an in-depth explanation on what `keyof` and `typeof` does, there's [an excellent question and thread that explains it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377365/what-does-keyof-typeof-mean-in-typescript).

```
enum Color {
    Green = "green",
    Red = "red"

}

let index: keyof typeof Color;
index = "Green" 

console.log(Color[index])
```

See working example on [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=26#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9gGzgJygbwFBW1A4s4UKAXigCIBzA0MgGixwCVgATE8glsjDAXx4TAALlACWIFsAAeALigBrYAE84AMyhClAB2BrYiFAG4M4yVPZl8hEGSg8AxnBABnRMAB0SCgAp4SZADaptIAugCUQA).