# How to set columnMode/... of a ngx-datatable without binding to ViewModel?

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I'm starting to use `ngx-datatable`.

I've currently this:

```
            <ngx-datatable
            #table
            class="material"
            [columns]="columns"
            [headerHeight]="50"
            [footerHeight]="50"
            rowHeight="auto"
            [limit]="10"
            [rows]="testService.tests$ |async"
            [columnMode]="'force'"
            [selected]="selected"
          >
          </ngx-datatable>
```

but angular isn't too happy with the `columnMode`: `Type '"force"' is not assignable to type 'ColumnMode'`.

I've been checking the exemple of ngx-datatable, and they actually seems to bind to `ColumnMode.force`.

I saw that I can import it in my component viewModel( `import { ColumnMode } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';`), but that would implie to declare a property here just to be able to bind to the ngx-datatable.

Is there a way to reference or specify the columnMode directly in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply **`columnMode="force"`** for your `<ngx-datatable>` element.

```
<ngx-datatable 
  columnMode="force"
  ...
>
</ngx-datatable>
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n15vtg)

---

**1.0** According to [ngx-datatable DataTableComponent (Line 186)](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/f870a877a88c3760e84748660933e92c98defe38/projects/swimlane/ngx-datatable/src/lib/components/datatable.component.ts#L186):

```js
@Input() columnMode: ColumnMode | keyof typeof ColumnMode = ColumnMode.standard;
```

It is acceptable to pass `columnMode` with a `string` value.

For the detailed explanation for the `keyof` `typeof` on a enum, you may refer to [@Yogesh's answer on What does "keyof typeof" mean in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62764510/8017690)

---

**2.0** According to [Angular - Property Binding docs](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding#binding-to-a-property),

> The brackets, [], cause Angular to evaluate the right-hand side of the assignment as a dynamic expression. Without the brackets, Angular treats the right-hand side as a string literal and sets the property to that static value.

Comment: Apparently, I was having an old version of ngx-datatable that was not allowing this. solved by upgrading the library