# Check if string exist in const typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some const like this

```
export class CustomerType {
  static readonly main = 'mainCustomer';
  static readonly additional = 'additionalCustomer';
}
```

And I have

```
const value = 'main'
```

Is it possible to check does value exist in CustomerType and return true or false?
I know that I can use include when is an array but this is class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get all properties on the `class` and then use [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to see if it is contained:

```js
class CustomerType {
  static readonly main = 'mainCustomer';
  static readonly additional = 'additionalCustomer';
}

const value = 'main'


console.log(Object.keys(CustomerType).includes(value))
```

You can see this working in [the typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCCuEAuB7AtgUwE4BUCeADhtAN4BQ00yYSAlsNFhmACYoB2Ie0aYt70ALzQA5L34Jk6bCIDcFKkhr1GzNp26sWtOhzAghorTtp6Qk1JixyyAXzJlgHZNABu++MWFi+7EQ8dnFBAMADoQFABzAAoAeQAjACsMYCRQgGsMPAhoi2lcQgwASlD+UHgWDBz3EE8ioqA).

Comment: Also with `Object.keys(CustomerType).indexOf(value) > -1`

Answer (score 1):

```js
type valueType = keyof typeof CustomerType

const value: valueType = 'main'; // no error

const value2: valueType = 'something else'; // throws typescript error
```

See an example in the typescript playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQYwNghgzlwMIFcoBcD2BbApgJwCoE8AHTYAbwChhgUJkBLEYbTCAE1QDsx9h0I6OwALzAA5HwGIUGHKIDclasloMmLdlx5tWdepwhhhY7brr6wUtFmzzyAX3LlkREgDcDCTAWJGA1pnxUADNgZ2Jg%20CQrHG9MRxBOFGB3ME8ALmSPLxcjcX4OW3IEjiSUzwAmDLLsnxFRKBlkAAsBAHNgTDAoTHkgA).

Comment: This is an interesting answer- I had to do some research to [understand how `keyof typeof` worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377365/what-does-keyof-typeof-mean-in-typescript).  But it seems it could definitely be used as a means of detecting a value was a property of the object.