# React-Typescript, redux toolkit - expresion of type string can`t be used to index type'Writable Draft'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Hello I have a problem I get an error as in title - expresion of type string cant be used to index type 'WritableDraft'. I would like to make it dynamic to avoid many "if" statements. Why it does not work state[action.payload.filterName]

after updating type definition, filterName: keyOf InitialState I get an error

```
Property 'push' does not exist on type 'string | string[] | WritableDraft<Recipe>[] | WritableDraft<{ recipes: Recipe[]; totalAmount: number; }>'.
  Property 'push' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

in a line:

```
addFilters(state, action: PayloadAction<FilteringConfiguration>) {
      state[action.payload.nameOfFilter].push(action.payload.content);
    },



filtering type: 

export type FilteringConfiguration = {
  content: string;
  type: typeOfFiltering;
  set: boolean;
  filterName: key of InitialState;
};

component: 
const onChangeHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const content = e.target.value;
    dispatch(
      recipeAction.setFilters({
        type: props.type,
        set: e.target.checked,
        content: content,
        filterName: "filterTypes",
      })
    );
  };



 redux toolkit
    
  

      const INITIAL_VALUE: InitialState = {
  recipes: [],
  likedRecipes: {
    recipes: [],
    totalAmount: 0,
  },
  recipeTypes: ["Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner", "Supper"],
  recipeTime: [
    "Very short (~30min)",
    "short (~1hr)",
    "medium (~3hrs)",
    "Long (~6hrs)",
  ],

  // variables for filtering recipes
  recipeTitle: "",
  filterTypes: [],
  filterLengths: [],
};
    
    const recipeSlice = createSlice({
      name: "recipe",
      initialState: INITIAL_VALUE,
      reducers: { 
    
    addFilters(state, action: PayloadAction<FilteringConfiguration>) {
      state[action.payload.filterName].push(action.payload.content);
    }, // there is an error
```

Comment: What is the shape of your ```payload``` and ```payload.filterName```?

Comment: it is 'filterName: string'. The problem is I can not assign string as index types. How to solve it?

Comment: You have shape and type of it as FilteringConfiguration and in component you can check how data is sent

Answer (score 0):

Because `INITIAL_VALUE` infers the types of your defined values and thus can only be mapped directly with names of properties (basically *keys of* your `INITIAL_VALUE`) and not string types.
You can define a type for your `initialState`

```
interface InitialState {
  recipes: Recipe[],
  likedRecipes: {
    recipes: Recipe[],
    totalAmount: number,
  },
  recipeTypes: string[], // you could define your own literal types/intersection of literal types here
                        // made it as strings just for shorter explanation
  recipeTime: string[], // here as well
  recipeTitle: string,
  filterTypes: string[],
  filterLengths: string[],
}
```

And then you need to make your `filterName` prop to be [keyof](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) `InitialState`

```
type FilteringConfiguration = {
  content: string;
  type: typeOfFiltering;
  set: boolean;
  filterName: keyof InitialState; // <--
};
```

Or the other option is to type `filterName` as [keyof typeof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377365/what-does-keyof-typeof-mean-in-typescript)`INITIAL_VALUE` if you don't want to extract your type to a separate type definition and want to leave it as you have.

```
...
filterName: keyof typeof INITIAL_VALUE
...
```

[Typescript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-LCAn6g5AAcjLFcYE-br217H0HSgADEa+Ue32B3Uigxdx8R99gcgwVON9AZ3PD18gZAuEvrtB17WoFuIDxT9CJwAJYATngyBvUdgS4btew-L8uF-f9PzGFcUCfPcUF3acWneVp4ygOA1V3O4NkYFlGF0d5tQQdhMhAHA1XsSZGGAAIBXiLCcMyep8ICXNtG4njeL47QxjTJDmgYHQ2iIUiJ1aRJkiY5AskwNpkFsOB6PI2YOCAA)
Redux toolkit has [Usage with Typescript docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript) which might help you in future.

Comment: But I get next error Property 'push' does not exist on type 'string | string[] | WritableDraft<Recipe>[] | WritableDraft<{ recipes: Recipe[]; totalAmount: number; }>'.
  Property 'push' does not exist on type 'string'. addFilters(state, action: PayloadAction<FilteringConfiguration>) {
      state[action.payload.nameOfFilter].push(action.payload.content);
    },

Comment: Could you please update your code in question?

Comment: Post was updated sir

Comment: Have you typed ```INITIAL_VALUE``` to be ```InitialState``` shape? Because you either do that and make filterName ```keyof``` of that type, or you either don't do that and make it ```keyof typeof INITIAL_VALUE```, i can't reproduce your error, might be a type mismatch somewhere.

Comment: I updated INITIAL_VALUE, yeah it is InitialState shape.

Comment: I have no idea how to overcome this problem

Comment: Try removing type casting ```[] as Recipe[]``` because you don't need them anymore, since you have all your types in ```InitialState``` type now.

Comment: I deleted type casting the problem is that key is 'string | string[] | WritableDraft<Recipe>[] | WritableDraft<{ recipes: Recipe[]; totalAmount: number; }>'. It takes types of values, how to solve it then?

Comment: @Kay did you manage to find a solution after all? I'm struggling with the same problem