# TypeScript cannot index type over generic reference

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Why is the following type code invalid?

```js
interface T0 {
  key1: string
  key2: string
}

type T1 = {
  [v in keyof T0]: string
}

type T2<T extends T1> = {
  [k in keyof T]: T0[k]
}
```

I get an error on the final line `Type 'k' cannot be used to index type 'T0'.ts(2536)`

I even tried adding an addition check on k to no avail

```js
interface T0 {
  key1: string
  key2: string
}

type T1 = {
  [v in keyof T0]: string
}

type T2<T extends T1> = {
  [k in keyof T as k extends keyof T0 ? k : never]: T0[k]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why is it invalid? Is that the question? Consider the range of `T` for which `T extends T1` yields true, and you'll realize that `k` can be pretty much anything. Not really sure what you're trying to achieve though...

Answer (score 1):

*"Type 'k' cannot be used to index type 'T0'.ts(2536)"*, is due to **strict** type checking. In your `T2`, you're trying to index `T0` with `k`, which is a key of `T`. However, `T` extends `T1`, and `T1` is a mapped type of `T0` where each key is a string. This means that `k` can be any string, not necessarily a key of `T0`. Therefore, it cannot guarantee that `k` is a valid key for `T0`, hence the error.

Please try;

```
type T2<T extends T1> = {
 [k in keyof T]: k extends keyof T0 ? T0[k] : never
}
```

Where, `k extends keyof T0 ? T0[k] : never` is a type guard. It checks if `k` is a key of `T0`. If it is, it uses `T0[k]` as the type; otherwise, it uses `never` as the type. This ensures that `k` is always a valid key for `T0`, which resolves the error.

Comment: I see, I think I fundamentally misunderstood what it means to be assignable. In particular, defining a variable from literal is different from "assigning" another variable of a different type

https://share.cleanshot.com/9myDJWBc

Answer (score 1):

[Type compatibility in TypeScript is based on structural subtyping.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html)

The constraint `T extends T1` means only that `T` must be assignable to `T1` — in this case it means that `T` must have a `key1` property whose type can be assigned to `string`, and a `key2` property whose type can be assigned to `string`.

The constraint doesn't prevent extension. Consider the following:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAZkG8BQzkDWEAngIwBcyAzmFKAOYDcehJATJTXSEzgL7McYYgAcUqUsgC82FgG0A0slCtiAexhp0AXU60GzATiGjxbADypkEAB6QQAEyppSAPmmz8i5SFUa0ulqK2oaCwmJoAMweuPhEZJQARAA2wJBQcMnU+jyJzHHsety8BcSRlCAArgC2AEbQ+aoALJS1amrJEHAgciEsAPT91mAIAHT8YaZoTR6oFqiRrozIg8gA8gQsK-0AegD8OEA)

```ts
interface T0 {
  key1: string;
  key2: string;
};

type T1 = {
  [K in keyof T0]: string;
};

type T2<T extends T1> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T0[K]; /* Error
                  ~~~~~
  Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'T0'. (2536) */
};

type T3 = {
  key1: "literal string";
  key2: string;
  key3: number;
  key4: boolean[];
  // etc.
};

type T4 = T2<T3>; // Ok
   //^? type T4 = { key1: string; key2: string; key3: unknown; key4: unknown; }
```

In the code above, `T3` satisfies the constraint `extends T1`: it has the required property and value types. However, it also has additional properties which don't exist in `T1`, so the mapped type cannot map the extraneous keys.

---

Regarding the conditional expression in the alternate mapped type:

```ts
type T2<T extends T1> = {
  [K in keyof T as K extends keyof T0 ? K : never]: T0[K];
};
```

Even if the property expression is evaluated to be `never`, the type of `K` in the mapped value type (on the right-hand side) remains as the initial value of `K`, which is still potentially a property that doesn't exist in `T0`.

Comment: Random question, how did you get the squiggles under `T0[K]`? Is there a way to copy that automatically out of the playground?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77429386/typescript-cannot-index-type-over-generic-reference/77429482?noredirect=1#comment136504072_77429482) @Tony I typed them. I’m not aware of any method to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you seem to implement the code of the situation below.

```
const obj = {
  item1: {
    item1Prop1: "item1prop1",
    item1Prop2: "item1prop2",
  },
  item2: {
    item2Prop1: "item2prop1",
  }
}
```

If it matches your case, try the code below.

```
type objType = {
  items: keyof typeof obj
}
```

if you want to know how it works, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377365/what-does-keyof-typeof-mean-in-typescript) will help you.