# How to find the key on javascript object

Tags: javascript

```
const shortCode = {
  DA: ['934', '986', '879'],
  BA: ['914', '926', '849'],
  AD: ['911', '900', '899']
};
```

How to get the Key on that shortcode Object. Let say I have '879' value and search for the corresponding key?

In Javascript.

Comment: did you searched for a similar solution on stackoverflow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a key in a JavaScript object by its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907419/how-to-get-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-by-its-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) of `shortCode`:

```js
const shortCode = {
  DA: ['934', '986', '879'],
  BA: ['914', '926', '849'],
  AD: ['911', '900', '899']
};

const res = Object.keys(shortCode)
                  .find(k => shortCode[k].includes('879'));
              
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 <script>
        const shortCode = {
            DA: ['934', '986', '879'],
            BA: ['914', '926', '849'],
            AD: ['911', '900', '899']
        };
        var f = '879';
        for (var k in shortCode) {
           
            if (typeof shortCode[k] !== 'function') {
                var arr = shortCode[k];
                for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    if (arr[i] == f) {
                        alert('key = ' + k);
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    </script>
```