# reactjs - country-data map

Tags: reactjs, country-codes

I am receiving an array of country codes as props like this: `['en', 'ro', 'da']`. What would be the best way to map it back to their names in an object like this: `{value: 'en', label: 'English}`.

Comment: Do you have the label in the Array? if not from where your labels will come?

Comment: @HarishSoni I don't. Working on someone else's code. I just have the code names.

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907419/how-to-get-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-by-its-value

Comment: So how you will know that which code belongs to which label?

Comment: Similar to your requirement https://stackoverflow.com/a/11796778/1188322

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this pattern:

```js
const myCountries = ['en', 'ro']; 
const data= [{EN: "England"}, {RO: "Romania"}, {DA: "Denmark"}];

const getCountriesOption = () => {
const countriesOptions = data.map(
  country => ({ value: Object.keys(country)[0], label: country[Object.keys(country)[0]] }))
      
  return countriesOptions;
    }
// All options
console.log(getCountriesOption());
// Only my countries
console.log(getCountriesOption().filter(
obj => myCountries.includes(obj.value.toLowerCase())));
```

Comment: I am trying this pattern with `const countriesList = countries.all.map(c => ({ [c.alpha2]: c.name }));` instead of `"en": "English"` etc and I always get None back

Comment: This is not clear, the snippet run flawlessly so you are missing something. If key exists, value will be returned. Provide the current structure of datasource and I can update my snippet

Comment: `countriesMap = countries.all.map(c => ({ [c.alpha2]: c.name }))` returns an array of objects that looks like this: `{AC: "Ascension Island"}`

Comment: countriesMap = countries.all.map(c => ({ value: c.alpha2, label: c.name }))

Comment: Shouldn't I pass the countriesMap to getCountry like this? `const getCountry = (shortName) => (countriesMap)[shortName] || "None"`

Comment: It depends of the structure of starting data. What do you have, a complex array with all the data or only an array of short codes as in the question ?

Comment: For the example that I am working on I am just passing `['en', 'ro', 'da']` but in the future I need to take account for every possible language that will be inside the countries library so I can't just use 'en': 'English' etc, maybe the next array will be `['de', 'en', 'el']` , I need to pass all the countries. I am trying to pass the countriesMap but It is still returning 'None'

Comment: your getCountry map/switch could contains any number of keys. If you pass in a existing shortCode it will return longCode. All other aspect of your implementation depends on the code you're working on so for further help you should provide a working snippet.

Comment: I am trying to use your getCountry function but instead of passing `"en": "English",
 "ro": "Romania",
 "da": "Denmark"` I am passing `const countriesMap = countries.all.map(c => ({ [c.alpha2]: c.name }));`  like so: `const getCountry = (shortName) => (countriesMap)[shortName] || "None";` When I try to run getCountry with a parameter of 'AC', I get 'None' back even though 'AC' exists on countriesMap as `{AC: "Ascension Island"}` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a snippet so I can adjust it ?

Comment: `const languageNames = ['EN', 'DA', 'NO'];
    const countriesMap = countries.all.map(c => ({ [c.alpha2]: c.name }));
    const getCountry = (shortName) => (countriesMap)[shortName] || "None";

    const countryOptions = languageNames.map(
        value => ({ value, label: getCountry(value) })
    )` , countries comes from the country-data library that returns all the countries like I explained like `{AC: "Ascension Island"}` etc

Comment: Update the snipped to reflect your data structure and remove unnecessary steps