# How to get a key of a value from a java script Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Following is an example of js object:

```
var arr =          
{
      "a1": { "0.25": 13, "0.5": 50},
      "a2": { "0.5": 50, "0.75": 113, "1": 202}
}

id = 'a1';
key = "0.25";

function myFunc(id, key) {
  return arr[id][key];
}
```

Using the above function I can get the value of the corresponding key.

My question how can I get the Key for a given value?

E.g. if id = 'a2' and value = 113, the function should return the corresponding key 0.75

Comment: Have a look at this answer to the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907419/how-to-get-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-by-its-value

Comment: It’s important to note that this is not a multidimensional array. There are no arrays in your code. This is an object where each key is a string and the values are objects. An array would be `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: I agree it's not an array but its an Object. thanks for correcting and thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Object.entries()` and `Array#find`

```js
var arr ={"a1": { "0.25": 13, "0.5": 50},"a2": { "0.5": 50, "0.75": 113, "1": 202}}

var a = 'a2',val = 113;

var Key = (a,val) =>  Object.entries(arr[a]).find(i=> i[1] == val)[0];

console.log(Key(a,val))
```

Comment: On Side note:- It's worth mentioning that find will give only the first matching value's key. if there are more than one matching value's it won't return all the keys

Comment: @CodeManiac .Op not mention multiple matching

Answer (score 1):

You can get keys for `arr[a]` first and than filter `key` based on `value`

```js
var arr ={"a1": { "0.25": 13, "0.5": 50},"a2": { "0.5": 50, "0.75": 113, "1": 202}}

let a = 'a1',val = 13;

let getKey = (a,val) =>  Object.keys(arr[a]).filter(e => arr[a][e] === val)

console.log(getKey(a,val))
console.log(getKey('a2',113))
```

If you're sure that there's always one key with matching value  or you want the first matching values key only than you can use `find` instead of filter

```js
var arr ={"a1": { "0.25": 13, "0.5": 50},"a2": { "0.5": 50, "0.75": 113, "1": 202}}

let a = 'a1',val = 13;

let getKey = (a,val) =>  Object.keys(arr[a]).find(e => arr[a][e] === val)

console.log(getKey(a,val))
console.log(getKey('a2',113))
```

Comment: How is that an array?

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar because i using filter in case there are more than one key which are having value than i am taking all the keys

Comment: I meant to the object to which OP is calling an array. You should state that's not an array in your answer.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar oops i thought were asking about the output of first snippet is in array :P OP already updated his question with proper naming

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.entries` to get the key

```js
var arr = {
  "a1": {
    "0.25": 13,
    "0.5": 50
  },
  "a2": {
    "0.5": 50,
    "0.75": 113,
    "1": 202
  }
}

function myFunc(a, key) {
  var k = Object.entries(arr[a]).flat();
  return k[k.indexOf(key) - 1]
}
console.log(myFunc('a1', 13))
```