# Return a key of an object based on value of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures

I want to ask if I have an object like this

```
const dataArray = {
    key1: ["a", "b"],
    key2: ["c", "d"],
    key3: ["e", "f"],
};
```

I tried

```
    const obj = Object.keys(dataArray).map((data, index) => {
        return dataArray[data];
        if (dataArray[data].indexOf("water") > -1) {
            return Object.keys(dataArray);
        }
    });
```

I want to return a key (key1, key2, key3) that has values of the string `"c"`.

How do I do that? please help

Comment: you can do it one liner `console.log(Object.keys(dataArray).find(k => dataArray[k].includes("c")));`

Comment: Pretty close to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907419/how-to-get-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-by-its-value), just needs to be adapted to search array values

Answer (score 4):

### You should know a difference about [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const dataArray = {
    key1: ["a", "b"],
    key2: ["c", "d"],
    key3: ["e", "f"],
};
const result1 = Object.keys(dataArray).map((data, index) => {
        return dataArray[data];
        // The line below do not affect !!!
        if (dataArray[data].indexOf("water") > -1) {
            return Object.keys(dataArray);
        }
    });
console.log(result1.join(',')); // All records from `dataArray`

/*******Find one item => using find*/
console.log(Object.keys(dataArray).find(k => dataArray[k].includes("c")));

/*******Find multiple items => using filter*/
console.log(Object.keys(dataArray).filter(k => dataArray[k].includes("c") || dataArray[k].includes("e")));
```

> The `map()` method **creates a new array** populated with the results of
> calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

> The `find()` method **returns the value of the first element** in the
> provided array that *satisfies the provided testing function*. If no
> values satisfy the testing function, undefined is returned.

> The `filter()` method **creates a new array** with all elements that *pass
> the test implemented by the provided function*.

Comment: @Goacgras Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You can get the entries of the object (key / value pairs) and iterates to get your desired key (if value includes 'c')

```js
const dataArray = {
    key1: ["a", "b"],
    key2: ["c", "d"],
    key3: ["e", "f"],
};

const entries = Object.entries(dataArray);

for(let entry of entries){
    if(entry[1].includes('c')){
        console.log(entry[0])
    }
}
```