# Iterate over an object and find the key

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this data set as

```
let data = {
  1: ['item1', '3435'],
  32: ['item2', '5465'],
  16: ['item3', '6577']
}
```

Now I want to find the key which contains the number "3435".
For this, I could not find out a way to iterate over objects. Is there any way to find a match without using iteration?

```
findKey(3534) // should return "1"
findKey(6577) // should return "16"
```

Comment: Does it always need to be the second element of the array? Or just any element in the array?

Comment: second element @Ivar

Comment: Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28191966), but change `object[key]` to `object[key][1]`.

Comment: Also note that JSON != a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can iterate like this. Not sure if we can achieve this without iteration.

```js
const getKey = (matchString) => {
  let data = {
    1: ['item1', '3435'],
    32: ['item2', '5465'],
    16: ['item3', '6577']
  }

  for (let item in data) {
    if (data[item].includes(matchString)) {
      return item;
    }
  }
}

const key = getKey('3435')
console.log(key)
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be:

```js
 let data = {
  1 : ['item1', '3435'],
  32 : ['item2', '5465'],
  16 : ['item3', '6577']
}

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {  
  if(value.includes('3435'))  
  {
    console.log(key)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't iterate directly over a JSON, but you can get the list of keys with `Object.keys()`.

From there, they are two choices:

If you know there is only one value matching use a loop to return the selected one

```
function findInObject(value) {
  for (let i in Object.keys(data)) {
    if (data[i][1] == value) {
      return i
    }
  }
}
```

returns `16`.

If there may be more than one entry use `filter()`

```
function findInObject(value) {
  return Object.keys(data.filter(elem => elem[1] == value))
}
```

returns `[16, 42, 1000]`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function searchByKey(data,Sval){
  let output
  Object.entries(data).forEach(each=>{
    let key = each[0] , val = each[1][1]
    if(Sval == val){output = each[0]}
  })
  return output
}
 
 
let data = {
    1 : ['item1', '3435'],
    32 : ['item2', '5465'],
    16 : ['item3', '6577']
  }

let s = searchByKey(data,"5465")

console.log(s)
```

**Note** this function is specific to your current data structure only

Answer (score 0):

You may leverage [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) method to retrieve key.

```js
const data = {
  1: ["item1", "3435"],
  32: ["item2", "5465"],
  16: ["item3", "6577"]
};

const getMatchingKey = (num) => {
  return Object.entries(data).filter(([key, value]) => value[1] === num)[0];
  // if you need all matching keys, remove the 0th index ===============^^^
};

const [key] = getMatchingKey("3435");
console.log(key);
```