# How can I find remaining percentages if one or two percentages are known

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

Consider the following Objects:

```
// Example 1

{
    gradeA: 100,
    gradeB: 'No-Data',
    gradeC: 'No-Data'
}
```

```
// Example 2

{
   gradeA: 50,
   gradeB: 40,
   gradeC: 'No-Data'
}
```

```
// Example 3

{
   gradeA: 75,
   gradeB: 'No-Data',
   gradeC: 'No-Data'
}
```

They represent a percentage, i.e. the sum of all three grades will be exactly 100. How can we interpolate the keys with `'No-Data'` whenever their values can be calculated?

Expected Results:

```
// Example 1

{
    gradeA: 100,
    gradeB: 0,
    gradeC: 0
}
```

```
// Example 2

{
   gradeA: 50,
   gradeB: 40,
   gradeC: 10
}
```

```
// Example 3

{
   gradeA: 75,
   gradeB: 'No-Data',
   gradeC: 'No-Data'
}

// Note: This one can't be figured out so we leave it as is.
```

My solution in pseudo-code:

```
function interpolate(obj) {
    // If only one key is a number:
    //    The value is 100:
    //        Set the other two keys to 0 and return the obj.
    //    The value is less than 100:
    //        return obj unchanged.
    // If only one key is not a number:
    //    set that key to the sum of the two numbers minus 100 and return the obj.
}
```

There are two main questions here:

1. How do I find out how many and which keys are `'No-Data'.`
2. Can I rearrange the control flow to be more efficient?

In reality, these Objects are inside an Array, but I'm sure I can figure that stuff out myself.

Comment: I guess you meant 40 in the `gradeB` field of the 2nd example

Comment: @GuerricP Yes. I've made the correction.

Comment: Apart from that your algorithm is fine and is working so I think you should post actual code and maybe do it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ which is more appropriate. Unless you have a more specific question about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28191966/15186629) to filter for a key given a value (in your case `No-Data`).

`let keys = Object.keys(obj).filter(k=>obj[k]===value);`

Just count the number of items in the array to see how many you have.

2. Your control flow is fine, it will be readable and its efficiency depends on how efficient you are at counting the number of occurances of `No-Data`. Tip: If you are trying to be as efficient as possible, you don't need to keep finding occurrences of `No-Data` after you find 2 :)

Ps. There are a few issues with the other code that was posted that will probably stop you from getting full points if you turn it in :)

Comment: That should do it! Let me code this up and I'll share it here if I can. Let's see if I can be efficient.

Comment: Good luck :) I'd second @GuerricP's suggestion to use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you are looking for a review. Another tip would be that at *some point* you will need to iterate over the object to count the number of occurrences of `No-Data` and you will also need to iterate to count the total (to see if it adds to 100). Doing these both in the same iteration will be twice as fast.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same logic you've described:

```js
function interpolate(obj) {
  var noData = 0;
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if (isNaN(obj[key])) {
      noData++;
    }
  });

  var sum = 0;
  var missingKey;
  if (noData == 1) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
      if (!isNaN(obj[key])) {
        sum += obj[key];
      } else {
        missingKey = key;
      }
    });
    obj[missingKey] = 100 - sum;
    return obj
  }
  return obj;
}

var objects = [{
  gradeA: 100,
  gradeB: 'No-Data',
  gradeC: 'No-Data'
}, {
  gradeA: 50,
  gradeB: 40,
  gradeC: 'No-Data'
}, {
  gradeA: 75,
  gradeB: 'No-Data',
  gradeC: 'No-Data'
}]

objects.forEach(o => console.log(interpolate(o)));
```

Comment: Its like I put my entire question through Copilot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my solution I analyze each object for the combined sum of the grades and the number of No-Data values. Then I proceed to replace the No-Data values in each property of each object if conditions match. Works with any number of grades.

```js
const objects = [{
    gradeA: 100,
    gradeB: 'No-Data',
    gradeC: 'No-Data'
}, {
   gradeA: 50,
   gradeB: 40,
   gradeC: 'No-Data'
}, {
   gradeA: 75,
   gradeB: 'No-Data',
   gradeC: 'No-Data'
}];

const analysis = objects
  .map( o => Object.values(o)
    .reduce( ([o, sum, nodatacount], v) =>
      v==='No-Data'
      ? [o, sum, nodatacount+1] 
      : [o, sum+v, nodatacount], 
      [o, 0, 0] ) );

for(const [o, sum, nodatacount] of analysis) {
  if(sum === 100 || nodatacount === 1) {
    for(const [key, _] of Object.entries(o)
      .filter(([_, value]) => value==='No-Data')
      ) {
      o[key] = 100-sum;
    }
  }
}

console.log( objects );
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {top:0; max-height: 100% !important}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first find numbers with `filter` and subtract that from the length to get a length of not numbers. Then if that length is larger than 1 and there is no max value you return same object. Otherwise you find total and create return new object with correct values.

```js
function interpolate(obj, max = 100) {
  const numbers = Object.values(obj).filter(Number)
  const notNumbers = Object.keys(obj).length - numbers.length
  const isMax = numbers.includes(max)

  if (notNumbers > 1 && !isMax) {
    return obj
  }

  const output = {}
  const total = numbers.reduce((r, e) => r + e, 0);

  for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    output[k] = typeof v !== 'number' ? isMax ? 0 : max - total : v
  }

  return output
}

const a = {
  gradeA: 100,
  gradeB: 'No-Data',
  gradeC: 'No-Data'
}

const b = {
  gradeA: 50,
  gradeB: 40,
  gradeC: 'No-Data'
}

const c = {
  gradeA: 75,
  gradeB: 'No-Data',
  gradeC: 'No-Data'
}


console.log(interpolate(a))
console.log(interpolate(b))
console.log(interpolate(c))
```